# Advantages of const in C++?

Tags: c++, constants

What are the advantages of [const](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const_correctness) in C++ (and C) for the uninitiated?

Comment: I think this is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455518/how-many-and-which-are-the-uses-of-const-in-c

Comment: You might find this useful
[StackOverFlow 455537](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455518/how-many-and-which-are-the-uses-of-const-in-c#455537)

Answer (score 12):

Const is particularly useful with pointers or references passed to a function--it's an instantly understandable "API contract" of sorts that the function won't change the passed object.

See also: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.4

Answer (score 11):

When used as a const reference in a function, it lets the *caller* know that the thing being passed in won't be modified.

```
void f(Foo &foo, const Bar &bar) { ... }
```

In this case the caller will know that the `foo` might be modified, but the `bar` will not. The compiler will enforce this when compiling the body of `f()`, so that `bar` is never modified and never passed on to another function that might modify it.

All of the above safeguards can be bypassed using `const_cast`, which is why such a cast is considered "dangerous" (or at the very least, suspicious).

Answer (score 6):

Seems pretty obvious - it keeps you from modifying things that shouldn't be modified.

Edit: for more guidance, always look to [Herb Sutter](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/006.htm).

Comment: ...by accident. :-P const_cast can easily override.

Comment: I was just about to say the same thing.

Comment: Though you should fear undefined behavior, if you use const_cast the wrong way...

Answer (score 5):

I'm not so convinced on the "safety" aspect of const (there's pros and cons)....however, what it does allow is certain syntax  that you can't do without const

```
void blah(std::string& x)
{}
```

can only take a std::string object... However if you declare it const :-

```
void blah(const std::string& x) {}
```

you can now do

```
blah("hello");
```

which will call the appropriate constructor to make a std::string

Answer (score 5):

Also, by using const, you state your *intention* for the use of a variable or parameter.  It is a good programming practice ("[C/C++ Coding Style & Standards](http://www.shift-right.com/openrepo/codingstandard.htm)", item 2.3).

Also by avoiding using #define's to define constants and using const's, you increase the type-safety of your code.
[C++ Programming Practice Guidelines](http://geosoft.no/development/cpppractice.html) - item 2.1

Answer (score -1):

The contract aspect of const is also important to the compiler's optimizer. With certain const declarations, optimizations involving loop invariants are easier for the optimizer to spot. This is why const_cast is truly dangerous.

Comment: The existance of const_cast and mutable explicitly *prevents* compilers from optimizing based on the const qualifiers.