# Is writing foo(const float&) wasted effort?

Tags: c++

When passing primitive types like int or float, is it wasted effort to write something like this:

```
foo(const float&);
```

rather than just passing by value:

```
foo(float);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing scalar types by value or reference: does it matter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982042/passing-scalar-types-by-value-or-reference-does-it-matter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For floats? [Yes, pretty much.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/738952/560648)

There's simply nothing to gain here: floats are small and the copy will not be slower than the creation of a pointer to implement the reference.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the implementation of references. As per Standard (§8.3.2/4):

> It is unspecified whether or not a reference requires storage (3.7).

references could, theoretically, save you from the copy of the `float`. That, of course, will be vain if references are implemented as pointers. Therefore the answer is implementation dependent.

Most of the time this kind of *micro-optimizations* don't make much sense. I highly doubt the bottle neck of your application is in the copy of that `float`.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that pass-by-value may in some cases enable a broader spectrum of compiler optimizations. Chandler Carruth (of Clang fame) spoke on some of the difficulties optimizing compilers face when dealing with references/pointers to objects in his [keynote at C++ Now 2013](http://youtu.be/eR34r7HOU14?t=39m1s).

Answer (score 0):

When passing primitive types like float, it doesn't help anything to pass by const reference. Passing by value accomplishes pretty much the same thing - any change made to the value of the parameter will not affect the value in the calling function (if calling by value) - no change can be made to the parameter (if calling by const reference).

With classes, however, passing a const class reference would be much more efficient than passing it by value (which would have to make a copy of the object).