# What is the meaning of 'const' at the end of a member function declaration?

Tags: c++, declaration, member-functions, c++-faq, function-qualifier

What is the meaning of `const` in declarations like these?

```
class foobar
{
  public:
     operator int () const;
     const char* foo() const;
};
```

Answer (score 1145):

When you add the `const` keyword to a method the `this` pointer will essentially become a pointer to `const` object, and you cannot therefore change any member data. (Unless you use `mutable`, more on that later).

The `const` keyword is part of the functions signature which means that you can implement two similar methods, one which is called when the object is `const`, and one that isn't.

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
private:
    int counter;
public:
    void Foo()
    { 
        std::cout << "Foo" << std::endl;    
    }

    void Foo() const
    {
        std::cout << "Foo const" << std::endl;
    }

};

int main()
{
    MyClass cc;
    const MyClass& ccc = cc;
    cc.Foo();
    ccc.Foo();
}
```

This will output

```
Foo
Foo const
```

In the non-const method you can change the instance members, which you cannot do in the `const` version. If you change the method declaration in the above example to the code below you will get some errors.

```
    void Foo()
    {
        counter++; //this works
        std::cout << "Foo" << std::endl;    
    }

    void Foo() const
    {
        counter++; //this will not compile
        std::cout << "Foo const" << std::endl;
    }
```

This is not completely true, because you can mark a member as `mutable` and a `const` method can then change it. It's mostly used for internal counters and stuff. The solution for that would be the below code.

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
private:
    mutable int counter;
public:

    MyClass() : counter(0) {}

    void Foo()
    {
        counter++;
        std::cout << "Foo" << std::endl;    
    }

    void Foo() const
    {
        counter++;    // This works because counter is `mutable`
        std::cout << "Foo const" << std::endl;
    }

    int GetInvocations() const
    {
        return counter;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    MyClass cc;
    const MyClass& ccc = cc;
    cc.Foo();
    ccc.Foo();
    std::cout << "Foo has been invoked " << ccc.GetInvocations() << " times" << std::endl;
}
```

which would output

```
Foo
Foo const
Foo has been invoked 2 times
```

Comment: What if I just make a const method but without a normal method, and then I call the method using a non-const object, my code usually runs fine. Is it wrong or harmful or something?

Comment: @KhiemGOM That's completely fine, and is pretty normal pattern for read only members.

Comment: `mutable` and `const` makes sense to me. But what I don't quite understand is that if a `const` member function would like a member value to be changed, why not just discard `const` and make itself a non-const member function? Does it have something to do with speed? Or it's like given two member variables, one has a `mutable` keyword and another one doesn't, in a `const` member function, we would like to only change the value of the variable with `mutable` keyword but want to keep another intact?

Comment: const functions can help speed. If the compiler doesn't see the function's implementation (its defined in the cpp file, or calls functions defined in the cpp file), then it doesn't know which member variables it might change. If any of the member variables is held in registers just before the function was called, and are used after the function call, the compiler has to assume the values might have been changed, and reload them from memory. If the member variables are not mute, then the compiler can deduce the function did not change them, and can skip loading them from memory after the call.

Comment: @UriRaz: Because of `const_cast`, the implementation cannot typically assume that member variables are left unmodified by opaque const member functions (unless of course it knows the complete object is const).

Answer (score 212):

The const means that the method promises not to alter any members of the class. You'd be able to execute the object's members that are so marked, even if the object itself were marked `const`:

```
const foobar fb;
fb.foo();
```

would be legal.

See [How many and which are the uses of “const” in C++?](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/455518/how-many-and-which-are-the-uses-of-const-in-c) for more information.

Answer (score 51):

The `const` qualifier means that the methods can be called on any value of `foobar`. The difference comes when you consider calling a non-const method on a const object. Consider if your `foobar` type had the following extra method declaration:

```
class foobar {
  ...
  const char* bar();
}
```

The method `bar()` is non-const and can only be accessed from non-const values.

```
void func1(const foobar& fb1, foobar& fb2) {
  const char* v1 = fb1.bar();  // won't compile
  const char* v2 = fb2.bar();  // works
}
```

The idea behind `const` though is to mark methods which will not alter the internal state of the class. This is a powerful concept but is not actually enforceable in C++.  It's more of a promise than a guarantee. And one that is often broken and easily broken.

```
foobar& fbNonConst = const_cast<foobar&>(fb1);
```

Comment: I thought the answer is about other const methods and not about const objects.

Comment: Thanks for the "The idea behind `const` though is to mark methods which will not alter the internal state of the class". That's really what I was looking for.

Comment: @JaredPar does this mean that any member function representing a read-only operation should be marked as `const`?

Answer (score 32):

These const mean that compiler will Error if the method 'with const' changes internal data.

```
class A
{
public:
    A():member_()
    {
    }

    int hashGetter() const
    {
        state_ = 1;
        return member_;
    }
    int goodGetter() const
    {
        return member_;
    }
    int getter() const
    {
        //member_ = 2; // error
        return member_;
    }
    int badGetter()
    {
        return member_;
    }
private:
    mutable int state_;
    int member_;
};
```

The test

```
int main()
{
    const A a1;
    a1.badGetter(); // doesn't work
    a1.goodGetter(); // works
    a1.hashGetter(); // works

    A a2;
    a2.badGetter(); // works
    a2.goodGetter(); // works
    a2.hashGetter(); // works
}
```

Read [this](http://www.parashift.com/c%2B%2B-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.10) for more information

Comment: A question on `const` member functions that doesn't mention [mutable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/mutable) is incomplete at best.

Answer (score 14):

Blair's answer is on the mark.

However note that there is a `mutable` qualifier which may be added to a class's data members.  Any member so marked *can* be modified in a `const` method without violating the `const` contract.

You might want to use this (for example) if you want an object to remember how many times a particular method is called, whilst not affecting the "logical" constness of that method.

Answer (score 13):

*Meaning of a Const Member Function* in [C++ Common Knowledge: Essential Intermediate Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321321928) gives a clear explanation:

> The type of the this pointer in a non-const member function of a class
>   X is X * const. That is, it’s a constant pointer to a non-constant X
>   (see Const Pointers and Pointers to Const [7, 21]). Because the object
>   to which this refers is not const, it can be modified. The type of
>   this in a const member function of a class X is const X * const. That
>   is, it’s a constant pointer to a constant X. Because the object to
>   which this refers is const, it cannot be modified. That’s the
>   difference between const and non-const member functions.

So in your code:

```
class foobar
{
  public:
     operator int () const;
     const char* foo() const;
};
```

You can think it as this:

```
class foobar
{
  public:
     operator int (const foobar * const this) const;
     const char* foo(const foobar * const this) const;
};
```

Comment: `this` is not `const`. The reason why it can't be modified is that it's a prvalue.

Answer (score 11):

I would like to add the following point.

*You can also make* *it a `const &` and `const &&`*

So,

```cpp
struct s{
    void val1() const {
     // *this is const here. Hence this function cannot modify any member of *this
    }
    void val2() const & {
    // *this is const& here
    }
    void val3() const && {
    // The object calling this function should be const rvalue only.
    }
    void val4() && {
    // The object calling this function should be rvalue reference only.
    }

};

int main(){
  s a;
  a.val1(); //okay
  a.val2(); //okay
  // a.val3() not okay, a is not rvalue will be okay if called like
  std::move(a).val3(); // okay, move makes it a rvalue
}
```

*Feel free to improve the answer. I am no expert*

Comment: `*this` is always an lvalue, even if the member function is rvalue-ref-qualified and is called on an rvalue. [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40fb31f48d184f16).

Comment: Updated. Is that okay?

Answer (score 7):

when you use `const` in the method signature (like your said: `const char* foo() const;`) you are telling the compiler that memory pointed to by `this` can't be changed by this method (which is `foo` here).

Answer (score 6):

Here const means that at that function any variable's value can not change

```
class Test{
private:
    int a;
public:
    void test()const{
        a = 10;
    }
};
```

And like this example, if you try to change the value of a variable in the test function you will get an error.

Answer (score 3):

The **const** keyword used with the function declaration specifies that it is a **const member function** and it will **not be able to change** the data members of the object.

Answer (score 2):

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-member-fns

> ## What is a "`const` member function"?
>
> A member function that inspects (rather than mutates) its object.
>
> A `const` member function is indicated by a `const` suffix just after the member function’s parameter list. Member functions with a `const` suffix are called “const member functions” or “inspectors.” Member functions without a `const` suffix are called “non-const member functions” or “mutators.”
>
> ```
> class Fred {
> public:
>   void inspect() const;   // This member promises NOT to change *this
>   void mutate();          // This member function might change *this
> };
> void userCode(Fred& changeable, const Fred& unchangeable)
> {
>   changeable.inspect();   // Okay: doesn't change a changeable object
>   changeable.mutate();    // Okay: changes a changeable object
>   unchangeable.inspect(); // Okay: doesn't change an unchangeable object
>   unchangeable.mutate();  // ERROR: attempt to change unchangeable object
> }
> ```
>
> The attempt to call `unchangeable.mutate()` is an error caught at compile time. There is no runtime space or speed penalty for `const`, and you don’t need to write test-cases to check it at runtime.
>
> The trailing `const` on `inspect()` member function should be used to mean the method won’t change the object’s *abstract* (client-visible) state. That is slightly different from saying the method won’t change the “raw bits” of the object’s struct. C++ compilers aren’t allowed to take the “bitwise” interpretation unless they can solve the aliasing problem, which normally can’t be solved (i.e., a non-const alias could exist which could modify the state of the object). Another (important) insight from this aliasing issue: pointing at an object with a pointer-to-const doesn’t guarantee that the object won’t change; it merely promises that the object won’t change *via that pointer*.

Answer (score 0):

In `const` objects only `const` methods can be called. All fielnd in such a method considered as `const` field.
Last issue has curious effect:

- pointer becomes a const pointer `int* const`, which is not the same as a pointer to const `const int*`. Thus you can alter the object which pointer points to, but can't make pointer to point to another object.
- reference should become a const reference, but it is invariantly a const reference: you can not re-init it to another object. But again you can alter the object which reference refers to.