# How does const after a function optimize the program?

Tags: c++, optimization, constants, keyword

I've seen some methods like this:

```
void SomeClass::someMethod() const;
```

What does this const declaration do, and how can it help optimize a program?

**Edit**

I see that the first part of this question has been asked before... **BUT**, it still doesn't answer the second part: how would this optimize the program?

Comment: This has been [asked before.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751681/meaning-of-const-last-in-a-c-method-declaration)

Comment: Why do you think it would "optimize" the program? That is not its purpose.

Comment: Well I always heard about how declaring const for a variable would help optimization. I don't see much point in declaring const in this manner if not to help optimize.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If the compiler knows that the fields of a class instance are not modified across a const member function call, it doesn't have to reload any fields that it may have kept in registers before the const function call.

This is sort of referred to the in C++ FAQ in the [discussion on const_cast](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.14).

Comment: +1 for addressing the optimization part with an explanation that makes sense. Are there any documents detailing this?

Comment: Also, I have a feeling that since field access is static, shouldn't the compiler already know if it needs to reload a field in a register or not?

Comment: I added a link. What do you mean about "field access is static"?

Comment: If other threads change class state ? If this may happen, compiler will wrongly cache data from previous methods.

Comment: @socketpair - yup, if doing multi-threaded programming using such a class instance, all bets are off!

Answer (score 5):

It tells the compiler that the method has no effect on the classes state; you can't assign to anything in it.  Have a look at the [C++ FAQ Lite 18.10](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html).

Answer (score 4):

The asm code that is generated for the const method will be the same if the const is there or not.  const is a function of the compiler not the runtime, so if there are any performance gains I would think that the compilers optimizer might use the const as a hint for things like inlining or determining side effects for a possible optimization.  So in short the optimizer might be able to help out a bit, but if the method is straight forward to begin with then I doubt that the code generated from the optimizer would be any different const or no const.

Here's an easy optimization I use (rather than hit and miss things like const) which take a second but pay off.  Organize your class variables so that they fall on cache line boundaries a little better, and put your most accessed variables together.  To do it just put your ints, doubles, floats, etc. together at the top of your class variable declarations and your odd sized variables at the bottom like so:

```
int foo; 
int bar;
double baz;
SomeObject obj;
char ch[14];
```

Comment: +1 for addressing optimization, though its a little bit vague. I had the same feelings that the code generated would be very similar.

Answer (score 2):

It allows you to call the class member function on `const` objects:

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    void foo();
    void bar() const;
}

SomeClass a;
const SomeClass b;

a.foo();  // ok
a.bar();  // ok
b.foo();  // ERROR -- foo() is not const
b.bar();  // ok -- bar() is const
```

There's also the `volatile` qualifier for use with `volatile` objects, and you can also make functions `const volatile` for use on `const volatile` objects, but those two are exceedingly rare.

Answer (score 0):

It prevents someMethod from altering any member variable of an object of that class.

Comment: ...or any method that will not do a const/c-style cast on this... :)

Answer (score 0):

My first thought regarding optimization is that since the 'const' indicates that the instance's state hasn't changed, the compiler possibly has more freedom with respect to reordering nearby calls to methods on that instance.

Comment: The compiler will not do this. const stops you from modifying the object but the function can modify other things, including the target of pointers in the object.

Comment: Thanks. I knew that the 'const' function could obviously change mutable internal state, but I wasn't sure if that necessarily ruled out being able to make this level of optimization since from the callers perspective the object is conceptually unchanged.

Comment: Nick actually means that pointers inside of an object can't be changed but what they point to *can* be changed even inside of a const member function. The following is possible: class { public: int *x; void blah() const { *x = 42; // but "x = 0xblahblah;" would be illegal here } };