# G++: Moving to another translation unit breaks "const optimization"?

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm working on presentation that demonstrates various C++ optimizations and stuck with an example where `const` allows them.

Consider following code:

**object.h**

```
class Object {
    int i1;
    int i2;
public:
    Object(int i1_, int i2_) : i1(i1_), i2(i2_) {}

    int getI1() const { return i1; }
    int getI2() const { return i2; }

    std::pair<int, int> calculate() const {
        return std::pair<int, int>(i1 + i2, i1 * i2);
    }
};
```

**constopt.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "object.h"

int main() {
    Object o(10, 20);

    std::cout << o.getI1() << " + " << o.getI2()  << " = " 
                << o.calculate().first << std::endl
            << o.getI1() << " * " << o.getI2()  << " = " 
                << o.calculate().second << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When `calculate()` is inlined, everything fine, G++ directly passes constants (10 and 20) to `operator <<` caching `getI1()` and `getI2()` calls:

```
mov    $0xa,%esi
mov    $0x601080,%edi
callq  0x400740 <_ZNSolsEi@plt>
```

But when I move `calculate()` to a separate translation unit, it forces `i1` and `i2` to be fetched twice (before and after `o.calculate().first`):

```
mov    (%rsp),%esi
mov    0x4(%rsp),%r14d
mov    $0x601080,%edi
callq  0x400740 <_ZNSolsEi@plt>
```

I see no difference, because `getI1()` doesn't rely on any side effects that can be created by `calculate()` and `Object` is intended to be const even when `calculate()` is in separate translation unit.

Is that G++ is not smart enough or it is not eligible to perform optimizations in such cases? My speculation is that it can cache `getI1()` and `getI2()` calls came from that answer: [How does const after a function optimize the program?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/810237/2709018)

I use gcc version 4.8.1. I have tried both -Os and -O2.

---

It seems that `const` isn't used in GCC optimizer in this case. Instead, it does its own digging (which can't be performed in different translation units), and searches for [*pure* and *const* functions](http://www.nongnu.org/c-prog-book/online/x1019.html). Functions can be manually marked with `__attribute__((const))`. Phase that eliminates extra `getI*()` calls is called **FRE** (Full Redundancy Elimination).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767395

Comment: Compilers do not optimize based on constness. Constness is only there to help the developers. `const_cast` is always there and the compiler has no way to know about it.

Comment: @sbabbi Can you find a reference for that? I'd be really surprised if that's the case

Comment: @Shade http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/081.htm

Comment: @sbabbi: `const_cast` is irrelevant, seeing as mutating a `const` object after `const_cast`ing away the naming expression's `const`ness is UB, and _does_ result in horrendous runtime oddities for precisely this reason.

Comment: Of course moving the definition of  `calculate()` to another file prevents inlining, the compiler has no idea what the function does if it can't see the definition. The definition could say `return std::make_pair(rand(), rand());`

Comment: Your edit makes it slightly clearer that you're asking about inlining of `getI1()` and `getI2()`, not calculate. That's still because the compiler doesn't know what `calculate()` does, and as Andrey's answer below shows, it could modify the members.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit OP question is about accessing a non-const object via const function. If `Object o` in the OP code was const, then the compiler would have been allowed to perform the optimization, (if it does actually perform the optimization is matter of debate, and I expect that it will not simply because it is a stack allocated object).

Comment: @sbabbi Hmm... `then the compiler would have been allowed to perform the optimization`... Contradiction? And I kindof meant a reference to the standard or something. That article was a very good read though.

Comment: @Shade, the standard doesn't discuss how compilers should optimise things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> because getI1() doesn't rely on any side effects that can be created by calculate()

It might do, whether it does or not is left unspecified by the C++ standard.

Even though you write `getI1()` and `getI2()` to the stream before calling `calculate()`, in C++ the order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified. That means the compiler is allowed to make all the calls to `calculate()` and `getI1()` and `getI2()` in any order, before doing any actual writes to `std::cout`. If it decides to make one or both calls to `calculate()` before the calls to `getI1()` or `getI2()` then it can't assume that the values of `i1` and `i2` haven't changed.

If you split the expression up then the compiler should be able to see that `i1` and `i2` cannot change until the calls to `calculate()`:

```
// this statement uses i1 and i2 before they can possibly be changed
std::cout << o.getI1() << " + " << o.getI2()  << " = ";

// this statement might mutate i1 and i2
std::cout << o.calculate().first << std::endl
        << o.getI1() << " * " << o.getI2()  << " = " 
            << o.calculate().second << std::endl;
```

> and Object is intended to be const even when calculate() is in separate translation unit.

But you didn't actually declare `o` to be `const`.

Calling a `const` member function does not guarantee that members *can't* be changed, it's more an informal contract between the caller and the function, not a guarantee.

Comment: I though that casting away `const` is UB (which leaves compiler hands untied), and that mutable objects should be `volatile`, but I'd probably mistaken. > But you didn't actually declare o to be const. < Yes, that actually enabled caching `getI1()` values in registers (I moved code to `void print(const Object& o)`)!

Comment: Casting away `const` is UB if the object is _really_ `const` i.e. declared `const` in the first place. There is no reason to use `volatile` for `mutable` members, they are unrelated.

Comment: Oh, now we have `const` and _really_ `const` objects, oh, C++! Anyway, thanks for the answer, it is both cleaned my mind and helped with my presentation.

Comment: It's always been that way. You have const objects, and you have what is called a "const access path" meaning an object is being accessed through a const pointer/reference, or via a const member function. You can access const objects through a const access path, but that doesn't mean they're actually const. Or in other words, seeing the `const` keyword not does imply immutable.

Answer (score 2):

Well, to answer your question exactly, one has to know the paticulars of implementation of the compiler. I don't, so what follows is a mere conjecture.

`Object::i1` and `Object::i2` aren't declared const. Therefore the compiler, without seeing the definition of `Object::calculate`, is obliged to presume they might change.

`Object::calculate` itself being const does not by itself preclude it from making changes into `Object::i1` and `Object::i2`. Consider the following slightly modified example:

```
class Object {
    int i1;
    int i2;
    int* p1;
public:
    Object(int i1_, int i2_) : i1(i1_), i2(i2_), p1(&i1) {}

    int getI1() const { return i1; }
    int getI2() const { return i2; }

    std::pair<int, int> calculate() const;
};

std::pair<int, int> Object::calculate() const {
    (*p1)++;
    return std::pair<int, int>(i1 + i2, i1 * i2);
}
```

Moreover, `o` is not declared const in the first place and therefore `Object::calculate` is entitled to do something as rude as `const_cast` and get away with it!