# what does it mean when you have "const" after your function name and input?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does const mean following a function/method signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549869/what-does-const-mean-following-a-function-method-signature)

Go ahead laugh at me, but what does the const after the function indicate?

```
int someFunc() const{  //<<----notice the const
    //insert code  blah...
}
```

If I wanted to a return type of const int wouldn't I just write

```
const int someFunc(){
    //code....
}
```

Comment: I'd say it's a duplicate too. I didn't know what I was searching for really, it's kind of an obscure thing to look for

Comment: By the way, the return types `int` and `const int` are 100% identical. The compiler ignores top level `const`s on scalar return types.

Comment: that makes sense actually, thank's @FredOverflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it means that the function can't alter any member variables.

```
class A {
void Func() const
{
  ++mI; // compiler error
}
int mI;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

It means that that function wont change object properties, except 'mutable'

Comment: thank's for the info, I feel @axon 's answer would be much easier to understand for noobs like myself :D . Thank's again

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://www.highprogrammer.com/alan/rants/mutable.html) for much detailed definition. It's a very good one.

Comment: I was just reading that actually :D thank