# non-member function cannot have cv-qualifier

Tags: c++, templates, constants

While writing the following function `abs`, I get the error:

non-member function `unsigned int abs(const T&)` cannot have cv-qualifier.

```
template<typename T>
inline unsigned int abs(const T& t) const
{
    return t>0?t:-t;
}
```

After removing the `const` qualifier for the function there is no error. Since I am not modifying `t` inside the function the above code should have compiled. I am wondering why I got the error?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Your desire not to modify `t` is expressed in `const T& t`.  The ending `const` specifies that you will not modify any member variable of the class `abs` belongs to.

Since there is no class where this function belongs to, you get an error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10982687/4809254 answer seems to be more accurate as in function add say `int add(const int a, const int b)`, we can't have const qualifier with this, as it is not a member function

Comment: @VikramOjha There are two kinds of `const`s in play in the question (one modifying the `this` pointer if/when the function is a member of a class; and the other one modifying the function parameter).  I believe both my answer and Bo's (the one you linked to) explains the cause of the problem the OP had, just worded differently.  BTW, the question mentions a function named `abs` with one parameter, not `add` with two, so I'm not sure where that came from in your comment

Answer (score 40):

The `const` modifier at the end of the function declaration applies to the hidden `this` parameter for member functions.

As this is a free function, there is no `this` and that modifier is not needed.

The `t` parameter already has its own `const` in the parameter list.

Answer (score 16):

The cv-qualifier on a member function specifies that the `this` pointer is to have indirected type `const` (or `volatile`, `const volatile`) and that therefore the member function can be called on instances with that qualification.

Free functions (and class static functions) don't have a `this` pointer.

Comment: Upvote simply because you explained `cv` which is what I was seeking.

Answer (score 3):

As we all know, `const` keyword followed after the argument list indicates that this is a pointer to a pointer constant.

There is a non-member function, it does not belong to the class, so add const opposite end error occurs.

**Solution to the problem:** is to either become a class member function or remove the `const` keyword const opposite end