# error: no matching function for call to 'boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex>::shared_lock(const Lock&)'

Tags: c++, boost, constants, mutex, boost-mutex

I have implemented a ReadLock like following:

In my myClass.h

```
#include <boost/thread/locks.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/shared_mutex.hpp>

typedef boost::shared_mutex Lock;
typedef boost::shared_lock< Lock > ReadLock;

Lock myLock;
```

In myClass.cpp:

```
void ReadFunction() const
{
    ReadLock r_lock(myLock); // Error!
    //Do reader stuff
}
```

The code works in VS2010 but failed with GCC4.0. The compiler is throwing error at ReadLock saying there is no matching function. I suspect is the "const" correctness problem with the variable myLock. When I removed the const in the function declaration, the error disappeared. Can anybody explain this to me? Why this works under windows but not with gcc?

Any suggestion here? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried mutable mutex?

Comment: mutable solves the problem! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either remove the `const` qualifier from `ReadFunction()`, because [qualifying a *non-member function* with `cv`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982628/non-member-function-cannot-have-cv-qualifier) or *ref* qualifiers is illegal and doesn't even makes sense; or you encapsulate whatever you are trying to do in a `class`.

---

```
void ReadFunction() const
{
    ReadLock r_lock(myLock); // Error!
    //Do reader stuff
}
```

`const` can only be applied to member functions. The above code isn't a member function, if it was, it would be, (for example, a class named `MyClass`):

```
void MyClass::ReadFunction() const
{
    ReadLock r_lock(myLock);
    //Do reader stuff
}
```

And in that case, you would typically need to make `lock` a `mutable` member. by declaring it like this:

```
class MyClass{
    ....
    mutable Lock myLock;
};
```