# constant function

Tags: c++, function-qualifier

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the meaning of a const at end of a member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059932/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-const-at-end-of-a-member-function)
>   [about const member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966319/about-const-member-function)

I found one function prototype as under:

```
const ClassA* ClassB::get_value() const
```

What does the above statement signify?  Can I change the member of ClassA object?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966319/about-const-member-function

Comment: Is your question, can I change members of a const object?  I presume you aren't the writer of get_value and aren't trying to change the ClassA object from within the body of the function.

Answer (score 2):

The first const means what it returns is a pointer to const A. So no, you can't change what it returns (unless you cast away the const-ness, which will give undefined behavior if the object it returns is actually defined as `const`, rather than returning a `const` pointer to an object that itself wasn't defined as `const`).

The second const means that `get_value` can't change any of the (non-mutable) state of the `ClassB` on which it's invoked (among other things, it's transitive, so `ClassB::get_value` can only call other member functions that are also `const`-qualified).

Answer (score 1):

No.

The ClassA pointer returned by that function is marked `const`. That means that you should not change any of its values.

It won't be *impossible* to change the values because there are various ways to get around a `const` marking, but you are clearly not *meant* to be changing it.

Answer (score 1):

> What does the above statement signify? Can i change the member of ClassA object.

`get_value` is a const member function of `ClassB` so it cannot modify any non-mutable data members of `ClassB` inside its definition. But it can however modify members of `ClassA`

For example the following compiles (leaks memory but that is not much of a concern here)

```
struct A{

   int x;
};

struct B
{
   const A* get_value() const
   {
       A *p= new A;
       p->x = 12;
       return p;
    }
};
```

Comment: @Saurav: This means the return object(A*) by method get_value() can modify the value of x, which is its member.Is that right?

Comment: No you can't change what the function returns because the return type is `const ClassA*` and not `ClassA*`

Answer (score 0):

`get_value()` is a **read-only** function that does not modify the `ClassB` object for which it is called. It returns a **read-only** pointer to a `ClassA` object. You can modify the object pointed to by this object by casting away its constness using `const_cast`. But the ideal thing to do is to make a copy of this object and mutate that.