# const at the end of one method giving error

Tags: c++, methods, constants

I don't understand why I get error with che const at the end of my method. The method print doesn't change any class member, right?

```
class Hello{

public:
   int get_member() {return member_;};
   void print() const {
       cout<<get_member()<<endl; 
   };

private:
   int member_;

 };
```

The error message is: 
  error passing "const Hello" as "this" argument of 'int Hello:: get_member()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Comment: You are calling a non-cv qualified function from a cv-qualified one. Don't do that. Declare `get_member` as `const` which it should probably be anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [constant function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348285/constant-function)

Comment: @CaptainObvlious : what does cv-qualified mean?

Comment: @FordPrefect const-volatile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int get_member() const {return member_;}
```

Should fix it. You can't call a non-const member from a const member as it breaks the 'promise' of const. If you could there would be no guarantee that the object isn't modified during the call.

Comment: Actually, you can, you just have to promise to the compiler that it's all right (casting). Reneging on the promise is punished with UB.

Comment: You are correct that the result of calling a non-const member from a const can be achieved through casting. I'm glad you pointed it out - it's good for readers of this question to know. However I strongly feel it should be added that changing the cv qualifiers on something needs very careful consideration before being done. If at all possible, avoid doing it.