# Why can't I access elements with operator[] in a const std::map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, constants, std, stdmap

I tried to use the `operator[]` access the element in a `const map`, but this method failed. I also tried to use `at()` to do the same thing. It worked this time. However, I could not find any reference about using `at()` to access element in a `const map`. Is `at()` a newly added function in `map`? Where can I find more info about this? Thank you very much!

An example could be the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, char> A;
    A[1] = 'b';
    A[3] = 'c';

    const std::map<int, char> B = A;

    std::cout << B.at(3) << std::endl; // it works
    std::cout << B[3] << std::endl;    // it does not work
}
```

For using `B[3]`, it returned the following errors during compiling:

> t01.cpp:14: error: passing ‘const
> std::map<int, char, std::less,
> std::allocator<std::pair<const int,
> char> > >’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘_Tp&
> std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare,
> _Alloc>::operator[](const _Key&) [with _Key = int, _Tp = char, _Compare = std::less, _Alloc =
> std::allocator<std::pair<const int,
> char> >]’ discards qualifiers

The compiler used is g++ 4.2.1

Answer (score 163, accepted):

[`at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) is a new method for `std::map` in C++11.

Rather than insert a new default constructed element as `operator[]` does if an element with the given key does not exist, it throws a `std::out_of_range` exception. (This is similar to the behaviour of `at()` for `deque` and `vector`.)

Because of this behaviour it makes sense for there to be a `const` overload of `at()`, unlike `operator[]` which always has the potential to change the map.

Comment: Is is possible to have "at" return a default value instead of throwing an exception?

Comment: I'm using `at()` with in VS2013 on a project set to use VS2010 toolkit. I thought that meant I wasn't using C++11... But yet it compiles... ??

Comment: I just need to comment that it doesn't make sense to omit the const operator[], which could also throw an exception for an unmapped element instead of changing the map.

Comment: @Spencer It would be surprising if the const and non-const overloads of operator[] had different effects. Normally, we expect that if some non-const objects or references in a program are made const, the program will continue to behave in the same way, as long as it compiles. Allowing only the non-const overload to throw exceptions can result in bugs that are not caught until runtime.

Comment: @Brian Did you mean to say "Allowing only the **const** overload to throw exceptions"?

Comment: @Spencer yes, sorry, that's what I meant.

Comment: @Brian Thanks for clearing that up. Of course, I disagree with the reasoning in your original comment...it's possible that you consider something a bug that I'd consider expected behavior, and vice versa.

Comment: @Spencer The "bug" in this case would be that after changing some non-const references to const references, the compiler would not warn you that some previously non-throwing operations have become potentially throwing. So then your program could crash in production because of the unhandled exception.

Comment: @Brian Trading a silent, possibly corrupting error for a noisy one. That's a good thing.

Comment: @Spencer no - in the status quo, there is no const overload of `operator[]`, so you get a guaranteed compile time error. If a const overload of `operator[]` were introduced with behaviour similar to `at`, then the guaranteed compile time error would turn into a runtime exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189089/discussion-between-spencer-and-brian).

Answer (score 40):

If an element doesn’t exist in a `map`, the [`operator []`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/operator[]/) will add it – which obviously cannot work in a `const` map so C++ does not define a `const` version of the operator. This is a nice example of the compiler’s type checker preventing a potential runtime error.

In your case, you need to use [`find`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/find/) instead which will *only* return an (iterator to the) element if it exists, it will never modify the `map`. If an item doesn’t exist, it returns an iterator to the map’s `end()`.

`at` doesn’t exist and shouldn’t even compile. Perhaps this is a “compiler extension” (= <del>a bug</del> new in C++0x).

Comment: Does the C++ standard forbid the implementation from defining additional non-standard member functions in library classes?

Comment: @Tim I believe the interface is fixed, yes.

Answer (score 4):

The []-operator will create a *new entry* in the map if the given key does not exists. It may thus change the map.

See this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/operator%5b%5d/).

Answer (score 3):

This comes as quite a surprise to me, but the STL map doesn't have a `const` index operator. That is, `B[3]` cannot be read-only. From the manual:

[Since operator[] might insert a new element into the map, it can't possibly be a const member function.](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html)

I have no idea about `at()`.

Comment: Could be a good idea to implement in a custom `map`.

Comment: The article link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) does not have a `const`-qualifier, which means that you cannot call it with a `const std::map`.
See also [What is the meaning of 'const' at the end of a member function declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/751681/5740428) if you're unfamiliar with this.

`operator[]` returns a reference to the element, just like `at`, but there is a key difference:

- [`std::map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) creates a new element if one doesn't exist in the map yet
- [`std::map::at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) (added in C++11) throws an exception if no element exists

Since `at()` doesn't need to modify the map, it has a `const` overload:

```cpp
T& at( const Key& key );
const T& at( const Key& key ) const; // <-- this is what operator[] is lacking
```

#### Non-mutating access in a `std::map`

Besides these two functions, there are three more ways to access elements in a `const std::map`:

```cpp
const std::map<K, V> map = { /* ... */ };

auto a = map.at(key);   // OK, C++11, throws exception if key not found
auto b = map.find(key); // OK, returns iterator (possibly equal to .end() if key not found)

auto c = map.count(key);    // OK, returns size_type (0 or 1)
auto d = map.contains(key); // OK, C++20, returns bool
```