# can't access const static std::map enum struct

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

I am trying to have a enum struct mapping to guarante a default value to a config value if it does not exsist and to guarante only access to "real" config values.(No std::string get)

So the Header looks like this:

```
enum ConfigValues
{
    LOG_LEVEL,
};

class Config
{
public:
    std::string get(const ConfigValues& key);
private:
    struct ConfigMapping
    {
        std::string configKeyString;
        std::string defaultValue;
    };

    const static std::map<ConfigValues, ConfigMapping> m_mapping;
}
```

And the cpp contains this:

```
const std::map<ConfigValues, Config::ConfigMapping> Config::m_mapping=
{
    {LOG_LEVEL, { "logLevel", "5" } },
};
std::string Config::get(const ConfigValues& key)
{
    std::string key = m_mapping[key].configKeyString; // <-- Does not work
}
```

But i cant access the map.

Comment: In Config::get(), both parameter and local are named key.  Is that a typo in the example code or the actual problem?  Maybe the actual compiler message might make things clearer.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134614/c-const-map-element-access

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`operator[]` is **not** const for a `std::map`.

Use [`at`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/at/) instead.

***Before C++11 :***

If you are not using C++11, you have to use [`find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/) which has a const version.

Comment: Ah right. Didn't see that. going to accept this in some minutes when it's enabled. Thanks for that hint.

Comment: I just updated my answer for people looking for the non-C++11 answer.