# How Do I access a map private member from public function member

Tags: c++

basically I can I access the private map from the constructor but not

from other members :-(

```
class FAnagramGenerator {
  public:
    FAnagramGenerator(){
        std::string len2[3] = {"blue", "red", "green"};
        std::string len3[3] = {"pink", "orange", "white"};
        std::string len4[3] = {"black", "yellow", "brown"};
        this->list[2] = len2;
        this->list[3] = len3;
        this->list[4] = len4;
        std::cout << this->list[3][1] << std::endl; // Works!!!
    };
    std::string getAnagram(int size) const{
        std::cout << this->list[size][1] << std::endl; // Doesnt!!
        return this->list[size][1];
    };

  private:
    std::map<int, std::string*> list;
};
```

thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Comment: Your `len2` etc variables are local variables, and go out of scope at the end of the constructor.  The pointers stored in the map are then invalid outside of the constructor.

Comment: You seem to have some basic misunderstandings about C++. You should take a step back and systematically learn the language from a  good book.

Comment: 'Doesn't!!' is not a problem description. You need to provide the error message you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `private`. It has to do with `const`.

Use `at`. If the key doesn't exist, `operator[]` on `std::map` will create it, so the operator requires non-`const` access. Using `at` instead of `operator[]`, which throws an exception if the key doesn't exist, will fix your problem.

```
std::cout << this->list.at(size)[1] << std::endl;
return this->list.at(size)[1];
```

Alternatively, you could remove the `const` qualifier from `getAnagram`, but the former solution is preferable.

Comment: You missed a major bug.

Comment: Are you going to tell us what major bug we both missed, or are you keeping the suspense going?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48179405/how-do-i-access-a-map-private-member-from-public-function-member/48179484?noredirect=1#comment83338959_48179405 Alternatively, carefully reviewing the code would help.

Comment: Alright, fair point. So there is a dangling pointer being left behind there that is easily missed. Perhaps you should post an answer addressing this part of the issue.

Comment: Nah, I find this style of "helpdesk Q/A" rather unproductive, both for OP as well as for future readers. I have given OP my best advice in a comment. C++ just cannot be learned by trial and error, it's just too weird at places.

Answer (score 2):

Your three arrays:

```
 std::string len2[3] = {"blue", "red", "green"};
 std::string len3[3] = {"pink", "orange", "white"};
 std::string len4[3] = {"black", "yellow", "brown"};
```

go out of scope after construction, and you end up with dangling pointers in you map.

You should use values of type [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead, which offer deep copy.

Other problem: your member function getAnagram is `const` while [operator[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) of std::map isn't. You have to use [at()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) (or [find()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find)) instead:

```
class FAnagramGenerator {
  public:
    FAnagramGenerator()
      : list { // better here in initialization list
         {2, { "blue",    "red", "green"}},
         {3, { "pink", "orange", "white"}},
         {4, {"black", "yellow", "brown"}}
      }
    {
        std::cout << this->list[3][1] << std::endl;
    }; // <- useless semicolon
    std::string getAnagram(int size) const{
        std::cout << this->list.at(size)[1] << std::endl;
        return this->list.at(size)[1];
    }; // <- useless semicolon

  private:
    std::map<int, std::array<std::string,3>> list;
    //            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::string getAnagram(int size) const{`

The const in this line of code means that you cannot call any functions that are non-const from within the function.

`operator[]` (which is a function hidden in the notation) is non-const (see [C++ const map element access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134614/c-const-map-element-access))

Instead, you should use [std::map::at](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) to get the element.

Comment: You missed a major bug.