# accessing std::shared_ptr<std::map<>> without using "get"

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, stdmap

I think this is a standard question but still I'm unable to find a solution or this. I might be missing something very basic.

All I want to do is to access (read only) the data within a `std::shared_ptr<std::map<int, int>>`.
The only way I could find is to actually get the object beneath the shared pointer and use it as a normal object:

```
shared_ptr<map<int, int>> tmap = 
       make_shared<const map<int,int>>(initializer_list<std::map<int,int>::value_type>{{1, 1}});
auto someMap = *(tmap.get());
cout << someMap[1];
```

Though this works I would prefer to use it as a shared_ptr if possible.

I was able to find this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947579/why-isnt-there-a-stdshared-ptrt-specialisation) related to the "[]" operator for shared pointers but again i am not sure on how to use it.
For the sake of completeness I would also like to know how to modify this data as well.

TIA

Edit: removed the const from the shared_ptr. Please note that my focus is on accessing the data inside of the shared pointer of a map and not the const part of it.

Comment: `std::map::operator[]` is non-const, and so cannot be called on a `const map` object. If you want to call it on the map pointed to by `tmap`, drop `const` from its type, then write `(*tmap)[1]`

Comment: Alternatively, consider `tmap->at(1)` - [`at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) will throw an exception if the key isn't found in the `map`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ const map element access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134614/c-const-map-element-access)

Comment: `auto someMap = *(tmap.get());` makes a *copy* of the `map`. To avoid that, use a reference instead: `const auto &someMap = ...`. But like others said, `operator[]` doesn't work on a `const map`, so drop the `const`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the API I am looking for is `at()` as I can use this API directly on the pointer (irrespective of whether the map is const or not)

```
auto& someMap = *(tmap.get()); // get the reference to the map instead of copy.
try {
    // either use reference to be able to modify the non-const map
    // or use the "at" api to access the element without [] operator.
    cout << someMap[1] << tmap->at(2);
} catch (const std::out_of_range& oor) {
    cout << "Out of Range error: " << oor.what() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`shared_ptr` supports pointer semantics, so instead of using `get`, you may just use `*` or `->` to access. `get` is usually avoided in most production code for the most part as it returns the raw pointer. By the way, you can/should also check if `shared_ptr` is null like you would check a raw pointer.