# error: passing const xxx as 'this' argument of member function discards qualifiers

Tags: c++, member-functions, const-correctness, stdset, function-qualifier

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class StudentT {

public:
    int id;
    string name;
public:
    StudentT(int _id, string _name) : id(_id), name(_name) {
    }
    int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    string getName() {
        return name;
    }
};

inline bool operator< (StudentT s1, StudentT s2) {
    return s1.getId() < s2.getId();
}

int main() {

    set<StudentT> st;
    StudentT s1(0, "Tom");
    StudentT s2(1, "Tim");
    st.insert(s1);
    st.insert(s2);
    set<StudentT> :: iterator itr;
    for (itr = st.begin(); itr != st.end(); itr++) {
        cout << itr->getId() << " " << itr->getName() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In line:

```
cout << itr->getId() << " " << itr->getName() << endl;
```

It give an error that:

> ../main.cpp:35: error: passing 'const StudentT' as 'this' argument of 'int StudentT::getId()' discards qualifiers
>
> ../main.cpp:35: error: passing 'const StudentT' as 'this' argument of 'std::string StudentT::getName()' discards qualifiers

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Where is line 35 in your code snippet?

Answer (score 598, accepted):

The objects in the `std::set` are stored as `const StudentT`. So when you try to call `getId()` with the `const` object the compiler  detects a problem, mainly you're calling a non-const member function on const object which is not allowed because non-const member functions make NO PROMISE not to modify the object; so the compiler is going to make a *safe* assumption that `getId()` might attempt to modify the object but at the same time, it also notices that the object is const; so any attempt to modify the const object should be an error. Hence compiler generates an error message.

The solution is simple: make the functions const as:

```
int getId() const {
    return id;
}
string getName() const {
    return name;
}
```

This is necessary because now you can call `getId()` and `getName()` on const objects as:

```
void f(const StudentT & s)
{
     cout << s.getId();   //now okay, but error with your versions
     cout << s.getName(); //now okay, but error with your versions
}
```

As a sidenote, you should implement `operator<` as :

```
inline bool operator< (const StudentT & s1, const StudentT & s2)
{
    return  s1.getId() < s2.getId();
}
```

Note parameters are now `const` reference.

Comment: Such a clear explanation. Thanks. 
But I wonder about your last code snippet. Why use reference in the function parameter ? `const StudentT & s1, const StudentT & s2` ?

Comment: @RafaelAdel: You use reference to avoid unecessary copy, and `const` because the function doesn't need to modify the object, so the `const` enforces this at compile-time.

Answer (score 100):

Member functions that do not modify the class instance should be declared as `const`:

```
int getId() const {
    return id;
}
string getName() const {
    return name;
}
```

Anytime you see "discards qualifiers", it's talking about `const` or `volatile`.

Comment: @Fred - Do you think it's definitely a requirement to add const modifiers to member functions that do not modify class instance ? Is there some other reason for the error in this case ? I doubt it because in most of the getters I write, I don't add const modifiers to it.

Comment: @Mahesh: Yes, it's part of [const correctness](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html). I'm not certain where the `const` is coming from here, but I suspect the `set` is returning a const reference from the iterator to prevent the instance from changing and thereby invalidating the set.

Comment: @Mahesh: Wouldn't pass my code review. I have a coworker who refers to me as the "const-able". 8v) Change that `foo obj;` to `const foo obj;` once and see what happens. Or pass a `const` reference to a `foo`.

Comment: @Fred - That is entirely different. I understand `const` objects can only call const member functions and const member functions can only call another const qualified member function. But in this case, I don't understand why std::set is storing it as `const StudentT` as @Nawaz mentioned.

Comment: @Mahesh: It's like I said -- if the elements in a `set` are changed, the order can be upset and then the set isn't valid anymore. In a `map`, only the key is `const`. In a `set`, the whole object is really the key.

Comment: @Mahesh: const are necessary otherwise you cannot call them with const objects. see the function `f()` in my answer.

Comment: @Nawaz - I understand const references. I was just wondering why std::set is storing it as a const object. And it is clear from @Fred's comment. Actually, I have never used std::set.

Answer (score 9):

Actually the C++ standard (i.e. [C++ 0x draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf)) says (tnx to @Xeo & @Ben Voigt for pointing that out to me):

> **23.2.4** Associative containers
>   **5** For set and multiset the value type
>   is the same as the key type. For map
>   and multimap it is equal to pair. Keys in an associative
>   container are immutable.
>   **6** iterator of
>   an associative container is of the
>   bidirectional iterator category. For
>   associative containers where the value
>   type is the same as the key type, both
>   iterator and const_iterator are
>   constant iterators. It is unspecified
>   whether or not iterator and
>   const_iterator are the same type.

So VC++ 2008 Dinkumware implementation is faulty.

---

**Old answer:**

You got that error because in certain implementations of the std lib the `set::iterator` is the same as `set::const_iterator`.

For example libstdc++ (shipped with g++) has it (see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01063_source.html#l00126) for the entire source code):

```
typedef typename _Rep_type::const_iterator            iterator;
typedef typename _Rep_type::const_iterator            const_iterator;
```

And in SGI's [docs](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set.html) it states:

```
iterator       Container  Iterator used to iterate through a set.
const_iterator Container  Const iterator used to iterate through a set. (Iterator and const_iterator are the same type.)
```

On the other hand VC++ 2008 Express compiles your code without complaining that you're calling non const methods on `set::iterator`s.

Answer (score 5):

Let's me give a more detail example. As to the below struct:

```
struct Count{
    uint32_t c;

    Count(uint32_t i=0):c(i){}

    uint32_t getCount(){
        return c;
    }

    uint32_t add(const Count& count){
        uint32_t total = c + count.getCount();
        return total;
    }
};
```

[image]

As you see the above, the IDE(CLion), will give tips `Non-const function 'getCount' is called on the const object`. In the method `add` `count` is declared as const object, but  the method `getCount` is not const method, so `count.getCount()` may change the members in `count`.

Compile error as below(core message in my compiler):

```
error: passing 'const xy_stl::Count' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

To solve the above problem, you can:

1. change the method `uint32_t getCount(){...}` to  `uint32_t getCount() const {...}`. So `count.getCount()` won't change the members in `count`.

or

2. change `uint32_t add(const Count& count){...}` to `uint32_t add(Count& count){...}`. So `count` don't care about changing members in it.

As to your problem, objects in the std::set are stored as const StudentT, but the method `getId` and `getName` are not const, so you give the above error.

You can also see this question [Meaning of 'const' last in a function declaration of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751681/meaning-of-const-last-in-a-function-declaration-of-a-class) for more detail.