# Error: passing const xxx as this argument of xxx discards qualifiers

Tags: c++, parameters, compiler-errors, constants, functor

I'm having an issue porting my functor from windows to linux. (a functor to pass to stl::map for strict-weak ordering)
The original is as follows:

```
struct stringCompare{ // Utilized as a functor for stl::map parameter for strings 
    bool operator() (string lhs, string rhs){ // Returns true if lhs < rhs
        if(_stricmp(lhs.c_str(), rhs.c_str())  < 0) return true;
        else return false;
    }
};
```

As linux doesnt support _stricmp but uses strcasecmp instead, I changed it to:

```
struct stringCompare{ 
    bool operator() (string lhs, string rhs){ // Returns true if lhs < rhs
        if(strcasecmp(lhs.c_str(), rhs.c_str())  < 0) return true;
        else return false;
    }
};
```

And it is now complaining about "const" parameters:

```
passing const stringCompare as this argument of bool stringCompare::operator()  
(std::string, std::string)â discards qualifiers
```

I'm not entirely sure why it supposes stringCompare should be a constant...

And the line where it is mad about this being instantiated is:

```
if(masterList->artistMap.count(songArtist) == 0)
```

artistMap being an stl::map with a string key.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I attempted to change the bool operator() parameters to const, as it appears that it's complaining about some sort of non-constant parameter passing. This didn't work, nor did changing 'bool operator()' to 'const bool operator()'.

As far as I know, strcasecmp is a const function so should case whether I pass it non-constant or constant parameters (c_str() also being const), so I'm not exactly certain where I'm going wrong.

I've googled similar issues but I still can't quite make sense of the issue from what I've seen both on stackoverflow and a couple other places.

The datatype where I'm using this is:

```
map<string, set<song, setSongCompare>*,stringCompare > artistMap;
```

Comment: Perhaps related to `const` qualifier?? Is the warning reported at the `map` declaration or somewhere else?

Comment: You are much better off using string algorithms which are portable and operate on std::string rather than const char*. there is one for case insensative comparison.

Comment: it's being reported at this line:

    if(masterList->artistMap.count(songArtist) == 0)


where songArtist is a string

Comment: @111111   I don't have access to external libraries such as boost, and stl doesn't have such a comparison function

Comment: possible duplicate of [error: passing xxx as 'this' argument of xxx discards qualifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973427/error-passing-xxx-as-this-argument-of-xxx-discards-qualifiers)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two things:

1. Define your `bool operator()` as `const`. It's just a good practice. This tells the compiler that this function will not have side-effects on the member variables of the class.
2. Add `const &` qualifiers to the `lhs` and `rhs` arguments. Passing constant references instead of copying memory all over the place is also good practice. By declaring references as `const` you're telling compiler that this function should not have side-effects on the referenced objects.

Your `operator()` should look as follows:

```
bool operator() (const string &lhs, const string &rhs) const 
{
  return strcasecmp(lhs.c_str(), rhs.c_str())  < 0;
}
```

Comment: @Glem Not `const bool operator()(...)` but `bool operator()(...) const`

Comment: I thought I had attempted it this way, but I suppose not! This did work.

Why does it require const after parameters? I haven't seen this before.

Also, shouldn't it in theory not worry about const if none of the internal functions are non-constant? Just so I can clarify in my head why the error occurred. Thank you!

Comment: @Glem `const bool operator()(...)` means return of the function is `const`, whereas `bool operator()(...)` means the function itself as `const`, i.e. not having side-effects on member variables of its class.

Comment: @GeorgeSkoptsov Ahh, that makes sense. Thank you George.