# Friending '>>' with own class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have the following class, which I friended with `cout` and now I'm trying to friend it with `cin` but I get an error... Could anyone help me, or tell me what I've done wrong?

error:

> c:\mingw\bin../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:2215:4: error: passing 'const RAngle' as 'this' argument of 'int RAngle::operator<(RAngle)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

class `RAngle`:

```
class RAngle
{
    private:
        int *x,*y,*l;
    public:
        int solution,prec;
        RAngle(){
            this->x = 0;
            this->y = 0;
            this->l = 0;
        }

        RAngle(int i,int j,int k){
            this->x = &i;
            this->y = &j;
            this->l = &k;
        }

    friend istream& operator >>( istream& is, RAngle &ra)
    {
        is >> ra->x;
        is >> ra->y;
        is >> ra->l;

        return is ;
    }
}
```

Comment: see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973427/error-passing-xxx-as-this-argument-of-xxx-discards-qualifiers) can help you

Comment: Given that the error is in `RAngle::operator<`, why not post that? I suspect the actual problem is that your operator overload should be marked `const`, and it is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not enough code to answer your question. But from error I would say you, that your `int RAngle::operator<(RAngle)` is not defined as const method and you use it somewhere, where you have only const.

Also, it's not very good practive to make `operator<` or other comparison operators return int, because this may lead to misunderstanding. Such operators should return `bool`.

So, there sould be something like this `bool RAngle::operator<(const RAngle& other) const { /*...*/ }`. This topic is covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++).

**Update** This code is completely strange. Why use pointers to `int`? Why make some data private? Constructor `RAngle(int i,int j,int k)` will not work as you suppose.

Comment: His `opertor>>` is a bit strange too.  I doubt that any pointers input from a stream will be usable.

Comment: Considering, that pointers do are not pointing to any allocated memory, yes. That code should crash.

Comment: Undefined behavior, rather.  Of course, if the file had been written by the same process, outputting pointers to objects which still exist, then it would be legal and work.  But how useful is that?