# error: passing 'const …' as 'this' argument of '…' discards qualifiers

Tags: c++

> error: passing 'const A' as 'this' argument of 'void A::hi()' discards
> qualifiers [-fpermissive]

I don't understand why I'm getting this error, I'm not returning anything just passing the reference of the object and that is it.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    void hi()
    {
        std::cout << "hi." << std::endl;
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    void receive(const A& a) {
        a.hi();
    }
};

class C
{
public:
    void receive(const A& a) {
        B b;
        b.receive(a);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    A a;
    C c;
    c.receive(a);

    return 0;
}
```

**@edit**

I fixed it using const correctness but now I'm trying to call methods inside of the same method and I get the same error, but the weird thing is that I'm not passing the reference to this method.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    void sayhi() const
    {
        hello();
        world();
    }

    void hello()
    {
        std::cout << "world" << std::endl;
    }

    void world()
    {
        std::cout << "world" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    void receive(const A& a) {
        a.sayhi();
    }
};

class C
{
public:
    void receive(const A& a) {
        B b;
        b.receive(a);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    A a;
    C c;
    c.receive(a);

    return 0;
}
```

> error: passing 'const A' as 'this' argument of 'void A::hello()'
> discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
>
> error: passing 'const A' as 'this' argument of 'void A::world()'
> discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Comment: `hi` is a non-`const` member function; `a` is `const`.

Comment: passing means as an (implicit) argument. Does not have anything to do with returning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: passing xxx as 'this' argument of xxx discards qualifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973427/error-passing-xxx-as-this-argument-of-xxx-discards-qualifiers)

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Your `hi` method is not declared as `const` inside your A class.  Hence, the compiler cannot guarantee that calling `a.hi()` will not change your constant reference to `a`, thus it raises an error.

You can read more about constant member functions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/const-cpp?view=msvc-160) and correct usage of the `const` keyword [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/const_correctness.html).

Comment: I changed to `void hi() const` and now it's working. Is it right? a void with const correctness?

Comment: Yes. The const tells the compiler that nothing will change inside that function. The return type is not relevant to this

Comment: In this case, since `a.hi()` does not change the object, this would be correct.  It also helps inform other programmers that this is a "read-only" method, and is guaranteed not mutate the object in any way.

Comment: The `const` after `void hi()` applies to the implicit `A* this` (thus making it `const A* this`), not the return type.

Answer (score 1):

1. As already mentioned, one option is to make `hi` method const-qualified.
2. Another option is to use const_cast at the time of calling the `hi` method like so

> ```
> A& ref = const_cast <A&>(a);
> ref.hi();
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
// **const object can call only const member function()** 

// **Modified Code**

#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    void hi() const {
        std::cout << "hi." << std::endl;
    }
};

class B {
public:
    void receive(const A& a) {
        a.hi();
    }
};

class C {
public:
    void receive(const A& a) {
        B b;
        b.receive(a);
    }
};

int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);

    #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
    freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
    #endif

    A a;
    C c;
    c.receive(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Encouraging the use of `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` in an answer on Stack Overflow is really asking for downvotes. [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/10871073)