# error: passing 'const …' as 'this' argument of '…' discards qualifiers in calling method

Tags: c++, member-functions

I'm passing the reference of an object to a function and I used const to indicate that it's read-only method, but if I call another method inside of that method this error occur, even if I'm not passing the reference as argument.

> error: passing 'const A' as 'this' argument of 'void A::hello()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
>
> error: passing 'const A' as 'this' argument of 'void A::world()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    void sayhi() const
    {
        hello();
        world();
    }

    void hello()
    {
        std::cout << "world" << std::endl;
    }

    void world()
    {
        std::cout << "world" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    void receive(const A& a) {
        a.sayhi();
    }
};

class C
{
public:
    void receive(const A& a) {
        B b;
        b.receive(a);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    A a;
    C c;
    c.receive(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what happend to *shortest* code necessary....

Comment: A method marked as `const` should only call `const` methods and not attempt to modify member variable (other than `mutable`).

Comment: _"...even if I'm not passing the reference as argument."_ You are passing it, because of the implicit `this` argument.

Comment: @Oktalist - Sorry for my ignorance, but what you mean?

Comment: @MrAlmighty `hello(); world();` actually means `this->hello(); this->world();`.

Comment: @Oktalist - But where am I passing anything as reference? I don't get it.

Comment: When `sayhi` is called via `a.sayhi()`, `this` points to the same object which `a` refers to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: passing 'const …' as 'this' argument of '…' discards qualifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26963510/error-passing-const-as-this-argument-of-discards-qualifiers)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since `sayhi()` is `const`, then all functions it calls must also be declared `const`, in this case `hello()` and `world()`. Your compiler is warning you about your [const-correctness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136880/sell-me-on-const-correctness).

Comment: The program is ill-formed. Those aren't "warnings".

Comment: I shouldn't have used the word "warning" because I didn't mean to imply that they were compiler warnings. I meant it was.... "advising" them, I don't have a great vocabulary :)

Comment: The word you're looking for is "ill-formed", or "error" :-) In fact, the program is ill-formed even if you don't try to compile it.