# passing const as this argument discards qualifiers only when using a unordered_map but not a vector

Tags: c++, constants

I understand that calling a non-const method to a constant object gives an error as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26963510/error-passing-const-as-this-argument-of-discards-qualifiers). This question, although deals with *the same* error, *is not* a duplicate because it is not about a non-constant method.

This time I have a minimal reproducible example:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

class Something
{
public:
    int m_value;
    Something(): m_value{0} { myVector.push_back(1); myMap["hello"]=3; }
    void setValue(int value) { m_value = value; }
    int getValue() { return m_value ; }
    //int getValue(const int value){ return myVector[value]  ;  }  //<-- this gives an error (just reference)
    int getValue(const int value)const { return myVector[value];    }
    //int getValue2(const std::string &name) {return myMap[name];   }  //<--- this gives an error (just reference)
    int getValue2(const std::string &name) const {return myMap[name];   } //HERE this gives an error (this question)
    
   std::vector<int> myVector;
   std::unordered_map<std::string,int> myMap;
   
};
 
int main()
{
    const Something something{}; // calls default constructor
                
    int l= something.getValue(0);
    std::cout<<l<<std::endl;
    
    l= something.getValue2("hello");  //<-- HERE the error
    std::cout<<l<<std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

In comments there are two method declarations that illustrates the point about non-constant methods. I left them there for reference. This question is not above them.

You see the const `getValue` method that returns a vector element? This works without problem.
Now see the const `getValue2` method that should return a unordered map element? *Even though* it is a constant method it generates an error

```
In member function 'int Something::getValue2(const string&) const':
17:68: error: passing 'const std::unordered_map<std::basic_string<char>, int>' as 'this' argument of 'std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = std::basic_string<char>; _Tp = int; _Hash = std::hash<std::basic_string<char> >; _Pred = std::equal_to<std::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, int> >; std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::mapped_type = int; std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::key_type = std::basic_string<char>]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

My question is: Why *only with unordered maps* passing constant as the index generates this error?

EDIT:
Thanks to the very useful answers. I modified the class to

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

class Something
{
public:
    int m_value;
    Something(): m_value{0} { myVector.push_back(1); myMap["hello"]=3; }
    void setValue(int value) { m_value = value; }
    int getValue() { return m_value ; }
    //int getValue(const int value){ return myVector[value]  ;  }  //<-- this gives an error
    int getValue(const int value)const { return myVector[value];    }
    //int getValue2(const std::string &name) {return myMap[name];   }  //<--- this gives an error
   //this will generate an exception if name is not in the map
    int getValue3(const std::string &name) const {
              //return myMap[name]; 
                return myMap.at(name);}
    int getValue2(const std::string &name) const {
            auto iter = myMap.find(name);
            return (iter != myMap.end()) ? iter->second : 0;
}
    
    
   std::vector<int> myVector;
   std::unordered_map<std::string,int> myMap;
   
};
```

Comment: `map`'s `[]` is non-const qualified, while `vector`s is.

Comment: "...because it is not about a non-constant method." actually it is ;)

Answer (score 10):

The `const`-qualified version of `getValue2` only has `const` access to the members of `Something`. This means that it will see `myMap` with the type `const std::unordered_map<std::string,int>` and you cannot call any non-`const` member functions on `myMap`. The `operator[]` is a non-`const` member function (it cannot be made `const`, because it sometimes has to insert a value-initialized entry, namely when the key is not found in the map) so you get the error message about discarding qualifiers. To get around this, you can use `.at(name)` instead of `[name]`. This will throw an exception if `name` is not found in the map.

Comment: Reference to [std::unordered_map::operator\[\]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at)

Answer (score 4):

`something` is a `const` object, so `getValue(int)` and `getValue2(string)` need to be `const`-qualified in order to be callable on it.  That means the `this` pointer inside of them will always be pointing at a `const` object, so all operations on the object's data members need to be `const`-qualified as well.

`Something::getValue(int)` calls `myVector[value]`, which works OK because [`std::vector::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) has a `const`-qualified overload to provide read-only access to the elements of a `const std::vector` object.

On the other hand, `Something::getValue2(string)` calls `myMap[name]`, which does not work because [`std::unordered_map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) is not `const`-qualified at all, so it can't be called on a `const unordered_map` object.  A `std::(unordered_)map`'s `operator[]` performs an insertion operation if the specified key is not found, thus the `std::(unordered_)map` object can't be `const` when using `operator[]`.  To read an element from a `const std::(unordered_)map` without inserting a new element, you have to use the map's [`find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) method instead, which is `const`-qualified, eg:

```cpp
int getValue2(const std::string &name) const {
    auto iter = myMap.find(name);
    return (iter != myMap.end()) ? iter->second : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `std::vector` either has an element at a given index or the index is out-of-bounds, in that case a call to its `operator[]` invokes undefined behavior.

On the other hand, with the key alone you cannot determine if a `std::unordered_map` has a value for that key or not. You have to search the map.

To find if a `map` has a value for a key and use that value:

```
std::unordered_map<int,int> x;
auto it = x.find(3);
if (it == x.end()) {
    // element not found
} else {
    auto value = it->second;
}
```

`operator[]` does more than that. If the element was not found it does insert a element with default constructed value for the given key and returns a reference to the newly inserted value. It is more or less the same as:

```
std::unordered_map<int,int> x;
auto it = x.find(3);
if (it == x.end()) {
    it = x.emplace(std::make_pair(3,0).first;
                                   // .second is bool to 
                                   // indicate wether an element
                                   // was actually inserted.
                                   // In this case we know it wasn't present before
}
auto value = it->second;
// or simpler:
auto value = x[3];
```

The benefit of `operator[]` is that you get a valid element in any case, but the price is that `operator[]` cannot be `const`.

*TL;DR*

Accessing a vector out-of-bounds is to be avoided. `std::vector::operator[]` always returns an existing element (or invokes undefined behavior). On the other hand, looking up elements in a `std::unordered_map` that are not present is common. In that case you need to choose what to do when the element was not present. One option is `operator[]` that potentially inserts an element in the map, hence cannot be `const`.