# Why is iterating over the set and modifying element not allowed here

Tags: c++, reference, set, const-iterator, range-based-loop

In the following code, we cannot iterate over set `s1` using non-const reference. Why?

```cpp
#include <set>

struct st {
  unsigned int f;
  std::set<int> s2;
};

struct comp {
  bool operator()(const st &lhs, const st &rhs) const {
    return lhs.f < rhs.f;
  }
};

int main() {
  std::set<st, comp> s1;
  st x;

  for (st &m : s1) // compiler error here. requires const st&
    m.s2.insert(begin(x.s2), end(x.s2));

  return 0;
}
```

---

thanks to @super I found that it is logical for compiler to not let us use non-const reference to `std::set` members. Now how and where is this policy declared?

Comment: How would you make sure that the elements in the set are still unique after modifying them?

Comment: @super how does compiler know this? and throws error?

Comment: The C++ compiler knows this because that's how this template is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the C++17 Standard (26.2.6 Associative containers)

> 5 **For set and multiset the value type is the same as the key type**.
> For map and multimap it is equal to pair<const Key, T>.
>
> 6 iterator of an associative container is of the bidirectional
> iterator category. **For associative containers where the value type
> is the same as the key type, both iterator and const_iterator are
> constant iterators.**

Thus in this range-based for loop

```
for (st &m : s1)
```

you may not use a non-constant reference because constant iterators return constant references to objects pointed to by the iterators.

Actually a range-based for loop is defined the following way (the C++17 Standard, 9.5.4 The range-based for statement)

> 1 The range-based for statement

```
for ( for-range-declaration : for-range-initializer ) statement
```

> is equivalent to

```
{
    auto &&__range = for-range-initializer ;
    auto __begin = begin-expr ;
    auto __end = end-expr ;
    for ( ; __begin != __end; ++__begin ) {
        for-range-declaration = *__begin;
        statement
    }
}
```

So relative to your range-based for loop in this line

```
for-range-declaration = *__begin;
```

there is an attempt to assign a constant reference returned by the constant iterator to a non-constant reference.

Pay attention to that you created an empty set.

```
std::set<st, comp> s1;
```

So the loop in any case does not make sense.

Consider using a map instead of the set.

Comment: about the empty set: I removed non-related code.

Comment: @AliTavakol Relative to the error message this is unimportant.:)

Comment: how compiler finds it that it should treat iterator as const? how is it declared?

Comment: @AliTavakol It finds that when it generates the code for the range-based for loop.

Comment: but if we use std::vector, it compiles. even with range based for loop.

Comment: @AliTavakol Reread the quotes from the C Standard I provided.

Comment: I am trying to understand it, and how compiler detects that it should throw the error.

Comment: @AliTavakol  I already wrote that when the compiler generates code for the range based for loop it sees that there is an attempt to assign a constant reference returned by the constant iterator to the non-constant reference declared in the loop.  So it issues an error message.

Comment: if I want to manually define a container that does not allow non-const reference to its elements, could you help witb a very basic example? no std lib

Comment: @AliTavakol Just write a function for accessing elements of the contaner that returns a constant reference.

Comment: This is a high-quality answer and it would be worth adding it to the dupe target (https://stackoverflow.com/q/38768432).