# Wording of GCC's error message when calling lvalue-ref qualified member function on temporary object

Tags: c++, gcc, ref-qualifier

The following code does not compile, expectedly:

```cpp
struct A {
    void doWork() & {}
};
int main() {
    A{}.doWork();
}
```

My understanding is that the temporary `A{}` cannot bind to the `&`-qualified member function `doWork`, and this seems in line with this excerpt from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions) (my *italic*):

> […] member function of class X is treated as follows:
>
> - no ref-qualifier: the implicit object parameter has type lvalue reference to cv-qualified X and is additionally allowed to bind rvalue implied object argument
> - lvalue ref-qualifier: the implicit object parameter has type lvalue reference to cv-qualified X *and is **not** allowed to bind rvalue implied object argument*
> - rvalue ref-qualifier: the implicit object parameter has type rvalue reference to cv-qualified X

Also `clangd` that I use in Vim tells me

> '`this`' argument to member function '`doWork`' is an rvalue, but function has non-`const` lvalue ref-qualifier  deleteme.cpp:2:10: note: '`doWork`' declared here [member_function_call_bad_ref]

However, when I compile with GCC, I get this error:

```
$ g++ -std=c++17 deleteme.cpp && ./a.out
deleteme.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
deleteme.cpp:16:16: error: passing ‘A’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
   16 |     A{}.doWork();
      |                ^
deleteme.cpp:5:10: note:   in call to ‘void A::doWork() &’
    5 |     void doWork() & {
      |          ^~~~~~
```

which seems not as related to the error as the error from `clangd`.

On the other hand, I've read those two words, *discards qualifiers*, when erroneously calling a [*non-`const` member function on `const` object*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5973485/5825294); in such a case I understand the use of "discards", as the object has a `const` that the function cannot honor, so it should be discarded for things to work.

However, this does not seems to be the case for the code above, where the problem is, I understand, the rvalue-ness of `A{}` as compared to the lvalue-ness that `doWork() &` expects.

Is the wording of the error from GCC wrong or am I misreading it?

Comment: Why -1??? Please, explain why, so I edit the question to improve it.

Comment: @TonyK, removed, but how could that sting me? Isn't it just innocuous?

Comment: Yes I suppose it is innocuous here. But superfluous semi-colons can certainly cause problems inside a function body. (Also, it makes you look as if you don't know what you are doing.)

Comment: Anyway, to answer your question: it seems that gcc treats the `&` as a qualifier, like `const` or `override`. The error message could be more helpful!

Comment: The standard doesn't prescribe the wording of error messages, so there are no right or wrong ones as far as the law is concerned.

Comment: This is not really a language-lawyer question, since there seems to be no question about the standard text. Also, the "discards qualifiers" diagnostic is correct: ref-qualifiers are qualifiers too, just like const-qualifiers. Are you asking why gcc doesn't specifically say "discards ref-qualifiers"?

Comment: There are **tons** of wording misuse in the standard itself, and you care about the gibberish compilers puking out...

Comment: @cigien _the "discards qualifiers" diagnostic is correct: ref-qualifiers are qualifiers too_ Except that neither `A{}` nor temporary materialization conversion applied to it have qualifiers. And expressions don't have ref-qualifiers one could discard.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Oh, I interpret it as, the temporary `A{}` having a `&&` qualifier on it.

Comment: @cigien ppl often confuse "rvalue" with "rvalue reference" :/ Which probably what the author(s) of the diagnostic message did.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Oh, I think I see the issue. Yeah, I'm not using that correctly. Which is probably why the diagnostic made sense to me :p Not a terrible question then. Though I still don't like the language-lawyer tag.

Comment: @cigien, tag removed.

Comment: @cigien, I understand they are all qualifiers, but as I wrote in the question, in case of _non-`const` member function on `const` object_ the qualifiers to be discarded is the one of the object, whereas in the case of the present question, what would that be? Maybe the `&` qualifier of the member function? There's at least a difference in the "direction" (as in, discarding object's qualifier to adapt it to the member function or viceversa).

Comment: Actually, I think the diagnostic is not using the terms correctly, but I'm not sure. See LanguagLawyer's response to my first comment. Perhaps they can write an answer explaining the diagnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a case of a suboptimally worded error message in GCC.

My guess would be that in GCC's implementation, diagnosing a mismatch between differing ref-qualifiers shares some code with diagnosing a mismatch between const and non-const, and they reused the same error message.

I would encourage you to [file a GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=gcc&Bugzilla_remember=on&Bugzilla_restrictlogin=on&GoAheadAndLogIn=Log%20in) suggesting an improvement to the error message.