# Error when compiling: passing (something) as 'this' argument discards qualifiers

Tags: c++, oop

I am writing a code and this is a small part of a method i want to implement in a class that inherits from a base class:

```
const string & getType() const override {
    this->type = "Greedy";
    return type;
}
```

and this is the private part of the class:

```
private:

    const string type;
};
```

Also this is the method im overriding:

`virtual const string & getType() const = 0;`

when I try to compile the project i get the message:

`passing (something) as 'this' argument discards qualifiers`

I have seen similar questions but all of them did not have `const` in the class method that this message was appearing on. Here is a good example of one:

[error: passing xxx as 'this' argument of xxx discards qualifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973427/error-passing-xxx-as-this-argument-of-xxx-discards-qualifiers)

Where seems to be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know what `const` does? If you read up on it your problem should become clear. Btw, why does this getter set something? That's a confusing implementation and you might want to overthink it.

Comment: `this->type = "Greedy";` you can't modify the current object in a `const` function

Comment: `... getType() const` promises that the function will not modify `*this` as e.g. in `this->field = new_value`. You are doing exactly that.

Comment: That wouldn't work even if you removed `const` from the function since the member variable is also `const`. You need to initialize the member variable when the object is created. (And note that const member variables are usually not what you want even when you think you do.)

Comment: @chi thanks your comment really helped!

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks i totally understand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that

```
const string type;
```

is a `const` member. That means, after it's initialization you can't assign any new value to it.

The second problem is, that the getter is also marked `const`:

```
//                       VVVVV
const string & getType() const override
```

Meaning you can't modiy member data from inside this function. Not to mention that it's a bad design if a getter changes a value before returning it.

---

If this override of `getType` is suppsed to always return `"Greedy"` you could do something like this:

```
const string & getType() const override {
    static std::string greedyType = "Greedy";
    return greedyType;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i understand where the issue is. Essentially `const` getter promises that the members of the class wont be modified inside the method, as someone stated in the comments, so by me assinging the value "Greedy" to type i essentially change it.