# error: passing 'const Player' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]|

Tags: c++

I am doing a school project on C++ and I have an interface defined so I can't change the parameters and types of functions. I am having a problem with this error: `error: passing 'const Player' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]`. I read other questions on stackoverflow about this, but they didn't seem to work.
There are 2 classes in this problem. `Player` extends `Character` and has `abilities`. There should be a function that adds abilities to the vector array:

```cpp
Player& addAbility(const Ability& ability){
    abilities.push_back(ability);

    return *this;
}
```

The function type and arguments **cannot** be changed.

After that, there should be a function to get all the abilities:

```cpp
const vector<Ability>& getAbilities(){
    return abilities;
}
```

The `Ability` class looks like this:

```cpp
class Ability{
public:
    Ability(const string& _name, const float _damage){
        name = _name;
        damage = _damage;
    }
    float getDamage(){
        return damage;
    }

    void setDamage(const float _damage){
        damage = _damage;
    }

    const string& getName(){
        return name;
    }

    void setName(const string& _name){
        name = _name;
    }

private:
    string name;
    float damage;

};
```

The function type and arguments **cannot** be changed.

In the class `PlayerHelper` there should be a function to sum up all the damage of the abilities:

```cpp
static float getTotalPlayerDamage(const Player& player){
    float sum = 0;
    const vector<Ability>& abilities = player.getAbilities();
    
    for(int i=0;i<abilities.size();i++){
        sum += abilities[i].getDamage();
    }

    return sum;
}
```

The error is on this line:

```cpp
const vector<Ability>& abilities = player.getAbilities();
```

I tried `const_cast` but it didn't seem to work either.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The `getAbilities` function needs to be const. `const vector<Ability>& getAbilities() const { ... }`

Comment: `const vector<Ability>& getAbilities() const{` is the trick. The const after the declaration tells, that the function will not modify it`s object.

Comment: "I tried const_cast" - Note to your future self: Usage of `const_cast` is *highly* situational, and "trying" it is almost *always* an indicator of a problem in itself. If you find yourself thinking "I'lll just use const_cast", you're probably already halfway off the rails and hurtling to the river at the bottom of the gorge.

Comment: @user4581301: Well, it said the function's type and arguments can't be changed. It didn't say anything about CV qualifiers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973427/error-passing-xxx-as-this-argument-of-xxx-discards-qualifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **problem** is that `player` is a `const Player&` but `getAbilities` is a non-const member function and thus cannot be called on a `const Player`.

To **solve** this, you can make `getAbilities` a `const` member function as shown below:

```
//------------------------------------vvvvv---->const added here
const vector<Ability>& getAbilities() const{
    return abilities;
}
```