# Difference between virtual void funcFoo() const = 0 and virtual void funcFoo() = 0;

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a declaration in a cpp where a function is like:

```
virtual void funcFoo() const = 0;
```

I assume that can be inherited by another class if is declared explicit, but what's the difference between

```
virtual void funcFoo() = 0;
```

Is important to me improve my programming and i want to know the difference. I don't want a malfunction caused by a bad inherit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751681/meaning-of-const-last-in-a-c-method-declaration

Comment: Short answer: `const` correctness.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The first signature means the method can be called on a const instance of a derived type. The second version cannot be called on const instances. They are different signatures, so by implementing the second, you are not implementing or overriding the first version.

```
struct Base {
   virtual void foo() const = 0;
};

struct Derived : Base {
   void foo() { ... } // does NOT implement the base class' foo() method.
};
```

Comment: no, it's the other way around: the first function can be called on both const and non-const instances, while the 2nd only on non-const instances (I know it's complicated, I got it wrong too the first time :-)

Answer (score 17):

```
virtual void funcFoo() const = 0;
// You can't change the state of the object.
// You can call this function via const objects.
// You can only call another const member functions on this object.

virtual void funcFoo() = 0;
// You can change the state of the object.
// You can't call this function via const objects.
```

The best tutorial or FAQ I've seen about const correctness was the C++ FAQ by parashift:
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html

Comment: This is the best answer. The only thing that I mess is understanding what is the `const` object..

Answer (score 11):

The difference is that the first function can be called on `const` objects, while the second can't. Moreover, the first function can only call other `const` member functions on the same object. Regarding inheritance, they behave the same way.

See also the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.10) on this topic.

Answer (score 3):

The two virtual functions have different signatures but inheriting will work the same way. The former is a const method and can only support const operations (methods) and objects.

Answer (score 1):

const methods can not change the state of the object so the

```
virtual void funcFoo() const = 0;
```

will be called in const instances of this class with the difference of

```
virtual void funcFoo() = 0;
```

which could be called only in non constant instances.
Try to google for the const logic in c++.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness