# Const Member Function

Tags: c++, constants, function-qualifier

The const member function guarantees that no member variables can be changed by the member function unless they are marked as mutable.

That being said it guarantees nothing else?

Here is a real example.  I have a classes `EventHandler` and `EventDispatcher`.

```
class EventHandler
{
public:
   void registerHandler(EventHandler* handler) const   // Should this be a const?
   {
      EventDispatcher::registerHandler(handler);
   }
};

EventDispatcher   // Singleton Class
{
public:
   void registerHandler(EventHandler* handler)
   {
      mListeners.push_back(handler);
   }

private:
   std::vector<EventHandler*> mListeners;
};
```

Should `EventDispatcher`'s `registerHandler(EventHandler*)` be const?  It does not change its member variables, but it does change global state.

Comment: Are you asking if it's "ok" to modify non-member/static variables within a `const` member function? ("ok" meaning doesn't break the "rules" of what a `const` member functions intentions are)??

Comment: There's no single objectively correct answer. However, as a practical matter any attempt to infuse C++'s low level language features with higher level semantics, always run into severe difficulties, with net negative utility. For C++ it *is* often necessary to use the language features in ways restricted by mere convention, in order to emulate higher level features (e.g., think about using the preprocessor to implement modules), but that does not identify individual language features with the higher level concepts.

Comment: @txtechhelp Each time I write a member function and then add a const I go down this rabbit hole of wondering if this is the intended use.  I think to myself, "Yes, my member function doesn't change any of its member functions, but it does call transmogrify() which then calls defrangulate().  Is this really const?"

Comment: check this!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751681/meaning-of-const-last-in-a-c-method-declaration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, it makes no guarantees about any other state than the object itself. And I would say that there's no particular requirement that it doesn't modify global state. [If you take it to extremes, any function call does modify the current state of the processor - even if it's just storing the return address on the stack [1]].

But a more reasonable thing would be that a `const` member function like this:

```
 class myclass
 {
 private:
    std::vector<int> v;
 public:
    std::vector<int> getV() const { return v; }
 };
```

This will create a copy of the vector `v` - which in turn allocates memory (thus changing global state). An output function that feeds your object to a output stream would be a similar thing.

If a member function modifies some global state (in a way that isn't obvious), then it probably should be made clear in the description of the function (documentation is useful sometimes).

[1] Of course, the C++ and C standards do not state that the processor has to have a stack, return addresses, etc - the compiler could inline all the code, and not make any "calls" at all, or use magic to "remember" where to get back to - as long as the magic actually works, it's fine to rely on that.

Edit based on your edited question:

It's one of those that isn't entirely obvious in either direction, you would expect the `registerHanlder` to do something like "store the handler object somewhere". But since it's not modifiying the object itself, it may help to explain that it's updating the dispatcher class. Of course, if it's not actually updating the class itself, or using anything from the class, you probably should make it `static` rather than `const` - that way it's clear that it's not actually modifying the object itself.

Aside: As it is written, your code won't work, since `EventDispatcher::registerHandler` is not a static member, and your `EventHandler::registerHandler` is not referring to an instance of `EventDispatcher`. You would either have to make an instance of `EventDispatcher` as a global variable, or make `EventDispatcher::registerHandler` a static function and make `mListeners` a static member. Or something else along those lines.

Comment: I believe it was the idea of changing the global state that was confusing me.

Comment: I just want to make sure I have interpreted your answer correctly.  In my edited answer, EventHandler::registerHandler(const EventHandler*), should be const and I may want to add an explanation?

Comment: See edit in my post (in a minute or two if you are quick back!)

Comment: EventDispatcher is a singleton class.  I should have noted that.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

#### What does the const keyword behind a method declaration guarantee?

The guaranty is a contractual reminder, rather than 'physical' memory barrier.

Thus, if you implement the `const` keyword correctly, the compiler will be able to *help* you to detect possible bugs.

However, no C/C++ compiler will *stop* you from modifying the member state directly; neither via fields nor by casting the object reference to a pointer and modifying the underlying memory.

#### Is my const method allowed to change (local/global) state?

A `const` method is not allowed to change the **external behaviour** of the system, but it is perfectly acceptable for a `const` method to change the **internal state**.

In other words, after calling all `const` methods randomly a couple of times, the system should still provide the same behaviour it did initially.

On the other hand, if the `const` method feels like caching a time consuming calculation and reuse it for the next call, it should be allowed. Same goes for a logger class that logs statistics, but does not change the behaviour of the system.

Comment: I am not actually trying to access global variables.  It was just a simple example.  I think Mats Petersson's answer touches on my confusion when he mentioned global state.  Another example, a const member function could potentially lock another class's resource.  Changing the global state, but none of it's local member variables.

Comment: @user870130 it's about the behaviour, rather than state. In object orientation, behaviour is all that matters. I've updated my answer.