# C++ Operator Surchage Class Declaration

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

In my .h I have

```
const CResultats & operator = (const CResultats & desResultats);
```

when I write this :

```
CResultats CResultats :: operator = (const CResultats & desResultats) const
{
}
```

Why is it not working?
I'm new to c++... sorry if it's stupid.

Comment: Read this: [Meaning of “const” last in a C++ method declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751681/meaning-of-const-last-in-a-c-method-declaration)

Answer (score 1):

Declare the operator as

```
CResultats & operator = (const CResultats & desResultats);
```

and define it as

```
CResultats & CResultats :: operator = (const CResultats & desResultats)
{
}
```

You may declare (and define) the operastor as

```
const CResultats & operator = (const CResultats & desResultats);
```

However semantically it is an invalid declaration.

Comment: @Sadboy in that case change the return type of the operator to `const CResultats &`. Vlad's version is according to the assign operator's convention though (i.e. your definition is unconventional).

Comment: @BeyelerStudios and what purpose would `const` assignment operator serve? It's not about convention, it's about making sense at all.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz you didn't read the part of "change the return type" or am I misreading your question?

Comment: @BeyelerStudios you misread my question. The return type of assignment is absolutely irrelevant in what I was pointing out (and is a hack anyway, because assignment should be a statement, not an expression).

Comment: @Sadboy What are you not allowed to change? For example the definition of the operator is simply invalid.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Ah I get it! In my statement I refer to Vlad's version of the assignment operator, not Sadboy's. Sadly, I cannot edit that statement anylonger. The full signature would look like this: `const CResultats& CResultats::operator=(const CResultats&)`

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
const CResultats & operator = (const CResultats & desResultats);
```

Is a declaration of a function which takes a `CResultats` by const-reference, and returns a `CRFesultats` by const-reference.  The method itself is not `const`.

But this:

```
CResultats CResultats :: operator = (const CResultats & desResultats) const
```

Is a function definition for a `const` function which takes a `CResultats` by const-reference, and returns a `CResultats` by-value.

Those are two different things in two ways:

1. You declare the function to return by const-reference, but you define it it return by value.
2. You declare the function to be non-const, but you define it to be const.

If you want to definition to match the declaration, then you must change the definition to:

```
const CResultats & CResultats::operator = (const CResultats & desResultats)
{
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write "this", it's not "valid" because it doesn't fit the signature; it's different for the compiler

A member operator (function) having `const` at the end operates at `const` objects, as simple as that. In this case it doesn't make any sense, though, because the only sensible operation of this operator *is modifying the object*.