# Error: Qualifiers dropped in binding reference of type x to initializer of type y

Tags: c++

why does the following throw this error:

> IntelliSense: qualifiers dropped in binding reference of type
>   "string &" to initializer of type "const string"

**.h**

```
class A
{
public:
    wstring& GetTitle() const;
private:
    wstring title;    
};
```

**.cpp**

```
wstring& GetTitle() const
{
    return this->title;
}
```

**If i remove the const word, it stops complaining**, and yet i have never made any changes to the variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [binding of reference to a value of type drops qualifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27812119/binding-of-reference-to-a-value-of-type-drops-qualifiers)

Comment: I read that question before, and got nothing from it heheh.. So i guess this one is more useful!

Comment: The first answer's first paragraph says the same as the first answer here. The issue is the same, but clarity requires an edit, not a new question.

Comment: GetTitle function should return wstring instead of wstring&

Answer (score 31, accepted):

By returning a non-const reference to a member of your class, you are giving the caller access to the object as if it's non const. But `GetTitle`, being a const function, does not have the right to grant that access.

For example:

```
A a;
string& b = a.GetTitle(); // Allows control over original variable
```

Comment: ahhhh, is that because if they called the function and returned it into a `string&` instead of a `string` they could change the original value? Or am i off completely?

Comment: Hurrahhh, thanks buddy! marking as correct when i can!

Comment: This is a duplicate question.

Comment: @Cinch: It may be. But not of the question you linked. Just because the error message is the same, does not mean the question is. This one involves a const member function, and while the connection may be obvious to you or me, it will not be to a beginner.

Answer (score 4):

You can add `const` before the reference that would resolve the conflict as well, i.e. `const wstring& GetTitle() const;` and likewise for the .cpp file.