# error: qualifiers dropped in binding reference of type string to initializer of type const string

Tags: c++, string, reference, constants

Header

```
class Player {
protected:
    int age;
    string name;

public:
    int getAge();
    string& getName() const;
```

Definition

```
string& Player::getName() const
{
    return name;
}
```

I get the following error when using the `getName()` function:

> error: qualifiers dropped in binding reference of type string to
>   initializer of type const string

How do I fix it and make it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Qualifiers dropped in binding reference of type x to initializer of type y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30146562/error-qualifiers-dropped-in-binding-reference-of-type-x-to-initializer-of-type)

Comment: It may be a duplicate for it but there is no problem-solving answer in that question i could find.

Answer (score 1):

In order for it to be enforceable as `const` the return type needs to be a `const&`

```
const string& Player::getName() const
{
    return name;
}
```