# Clang: Binding of reference to a value of type 'const TClass' drops qualifiers

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, c++builder, c++builder-10-seattle

I have the following method which compiles fine using the "classic" bcc32 compiler, but fails to compile using the Rad Studio 10 Clang compiler.

```
TPersistentClass & __fastcall TService_REST_Server_Ol::OnServerMethods()
{
    return __classid(TServerMethods_RSO);
}
```

The compiler produces the following error:

> [CLANG Error] Service_REST_Server_OlU.cpp(37): binding of reference to type 'TPersistentClass' (aka 'System::TMetaClass *') to a value of type 'const TClass' (aka 'System::TMetaClass *const') drops qualifiers

If I understand correctly, based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27812119/binding-of-reference-to-a-value-of-type-drops-qualifiers), the reason this does not work is because the code is attempting to return a non-const reference to a const object. However, I am unsure syntactically how I go about solving this issue.  Is there a way to indicate in the method definition that I want to return a `const`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return a const reference you must declare it.

```
const TPersistentClass & __fastcall TService_REST_Server_Ol::OnServerMethods()
{
    return __classid(TServerMethods_RSO);
}
```