# Why am I getting the warning: "Binding of reference to type basic_string"?

Tags: c++, reference, constants

I am calling a function from within a function and passing a parameter as a const reference through both. When I compile I get warned (and also by the intellisense) that it is

> binding of reference to type basic_string

What's going on?

I thought I understood the situation, but I guess I'm not clear on it. These answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27812119/binding-of-reference-to-a-value-of-type-drops-qualifiers), [2](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjPiayqoJXPAhWGHT4KHY8HDDcQFggsMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F27126125%2Fqualifiers-dropped-in-binding-reference-of-type-to-initializer-of-type-const&usg=AFQjCNGpucXaEx_FuDDQOUKZRTmLjgaK_w&sig2=fmH5YBq30T7eZvwytUVOcA), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object)) all touch on forms of this problem. 
I thought because the parameter of the calling function is a `const &` and it's being passed as a `const &`, I should be good. a snippet of my code is below.

My function definition:

```
std::string joinPathAndFile(const std::string &path, const std::string &fname)
{
    boost::filesystem::path b_fname (fname);
    boost::filesystem::path b_path (path);
    boost::filesystem::path b_full_path = b_path / b_fname;
    return b_full_path.string();
}

void myFunction(const std::string &path)
{
    std::string file = joinPathAndFile(path, "fname.txt");
    std::cout << file << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    myFunction("/path/to/");
}
```

Comment: I cannot see any issue with the code you've shown.

Comment: @5gon12eder: I thought so too!

Comment: What compiler are you using? And is this the full warning message?

Comment: Maybe you've oversimplified it. Could you post a minimal program that can actually be compiled and still triggers the warning (see “[mcve]”)?

Comment: This compiles fine for me, but then I have no code in the joinPathAndFile() function. Perhaps you could post that code, or see if the problem is caused by something in that function

Comment: @5gon12eder: It really is this simple I swear. But I did update my OP

Comment: What line is the warning on?  Seems like that would narrow it down quite a bit.

Comment: After adding `#include <string>`, `#include <iostream>` and `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>`, both GCC and Clang compile the code happily even with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe I have some weird flag set. I dunno. Also sorry for ignoring the includes (I noticed they;re often left out on SO)

Comment: Did you try compiling the posted code in isolation and did it still produce the warning? If so, does the problem persist if you change the implementation of `joinPathAndFile` to `return path + "/" + fname;` and get rid of Boost? Wired problems like this usually have wired causes so it is important that we can see exactly the code that triggers the error and that code is as minimal as possible. And you are right that there are many questions on this site that are not a good example for this. ;-)

Comment: It probably would be helpful if you could tell us where exactly the warning is occurring and what the entire warning message is.