# Why const does not work

Tags: c++, constants

```
class Student{
public:
    Student();
    Student(string name, int score);
    string getName();
    int getScore();
    void insert(string name, int score);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Student& student){
        os << "Name: "<<student.name<<",Score:"<<student.score<<endl;
        return os;
    }
 private:
    string name;
    int score;

};


string Student::getName(){
    return name;
}
int Student::getScore(){
    return score;
}
```

I define above class

and main function I define a comparison function

```
int compStudent(const Student &student1, const Student &student2){
    int score1 = student1.getScore();
    int score2 = student2.getScore();
    if(score1 == score2) return 0;
    if(score1<score2) return -1;
    return 1;
}
```

Then the error is said this argument is const but function is not const.

Then I delete the const, it works why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to call `getScore()` on a `const` object, the method needs to be declared `const`:

```
class Student{
    ...
    int getScore() const;
    ...
};


int Student::getScore() const {
    return score;
}
```

See [Meaning of "const" last in a C++ method declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751681/meaning-of-const-last-in-a-c-method-declaration) for a discussion.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
int score1 = student1.getScore();
```

calls the `getScore()` method on student1, which is a const reference. But the `getScore()` method is not a const method (it doesn't promise not to modify `student1`).

To fix this, modify the method to indicate it is const:

```
class Student {
    // ...
    int getScore() const;
    // ...
};
```