# Is it possible change value of Member variable within "const" function?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Value of constant variable can be changed through pointer tricks, but is it possible to do something like this :

```
    class A (){
       int x;
    public:
       void func () const {
          //change value of x here
    }
}
```

Comment: *Value of constant variable can be changed through pointer tricks* - Sure, but it's not useful at all. Just because you can trick the compiler into that doesn't mean it's safe.

Comment: i understand, just asked out of curiosity and knowledge of tricks

Comment: Yes and safe if you mark `x` as `mutable int x;`

Comment: @jacky666 You see, the use of `const` is generally optional, its mostly something you use to tell the compiler a determined method is "read-only" and guaranteed to execute without changing any data in the class. When you violate that premise you defeat the purpose of defining a method as `const` to begin with. Don't do it. If your method does in fact change data in the class, then don't make it `const`.

Comment: The search is your friend http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751681/meaning-of-const-last-in-a-c-method-declaration

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Though this is not appreciated, but C++ provides “Backdoors” which can be used to breach its own regulations, just like dirty pointer tricks. Anyway, you can easily do this by using a casted version of “This” pointer :

```
class A (){
           int x;
        public:
           void func () const {
              //change value of x here
         A* ptr =  const_cast<A*> (this);
         ptr->x= 10;     //Voila ! Here you go buddy 
        }
 }
```

Comment: I believe you meant `const_cast`, and this is an incomplete answer.

Comment: and even if you `const_cast` ... doing it to an immutable object and modifying it is UB.

Answer (score 73):

declare `x` `mutable`

```
class A (){
   mutable int x;
public:
   void func () const {
      //change value of x here
   }
};
```

Comment: This saved me a ton of time! Thank you for this!

Answer (score 15):

You have two options:

```
class C
{
public:
    void const_f() const
    {
        x = 5;                               // A
        auto* p_this = const_cast<C*>(this); // B
        p_this->y = 5;
    }

private:
    mutable int x;                           // A
    int y;
};
```

- A: declare certain members mutable.
- B: const_cast to remove constness from the `this` pointer.

Comment: Isn't `p_this->y = 5;` undefined behavior?

Comment: Your Plan B is UB if `this` really points to an immutable object.

Answer (score 8):

The most important thing to understand here is [**bitwise/physical/concrete `const`ness** and **conceptual/meaningwise/logical/abstract `const`ness**](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#logical-vs-physical-state).

In short:

- If the function is *conceptually* `const`, make the member data `mutable`.
- Otherwise, make the function non-`const`.

Answer (score 0):

Just cast 'this', this would be a dirty way to implement your program, do avoid this if you are doing a project or teamwork as others would get confused by this.

```
    class CAST_CLASS (){
       int var;
    public:
       void change_CAST () const {

     CAST_CLASS* pointer =  const_cast<CAST_CLASS*> (this);
     pointer->var= 10;     
    }};
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers don't mention this, but following also modifies "x" (definitely, not advisable):

```
class A {
    int x, &y{x}, *z{&x};
public:
    void func () const
    {
        y  = 42; // x is modified now!
        *z = 29; // x is modified again!!
    }
};
```