# Invalid arguments when calling getter member

Tags: c++

The error happen when I try to use one of my get function on parameter inside  member functions. The error is:

> Invalid arguments '. Candidates are : int getTotalArea() .

here is an example from my code :

```
        class Apartment{
    public : // ...
enum SquareType {EMPTY, WALL, NUM_SQUARE_TYPES};

        bool operator<(const Apartment& apartment); // done - need help

        int getTotalArea(); // done

        private:
        int price;
        int length;
        int width;
        SquareType** squares;

    };


    int Apartment::getTotalArea()
    {
        int count=0;
        for(int i=0;i<width;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<length;j++)
            {
                if(squares[i][j]==EMPTY)
                {
                        count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    bool Apartment::operator<(const Apartment& apartment)
    {
        int thisArea=this->getTotalArea();
        int paramArea=apartment.getTotalArea(); // the error line is here !!!
//the error is Invalid arguments '. Candidates are : int getTotalArea() .
        double thisRatio=((double)price)/thisArea;
        double paramRatio=((double)apartment.price)/paramArea;
        if(thisRatio==paramRatio)
        {
            return price < apartment.price;
        }
        return thisRatio<paramRatio;

    }
```

Have I done something wrong ?

It's the first time I'm using c++ ... by the way - any comments for the rest of the code are fine as well.

Comment: If you have errors you should share them.  It is not nice to horde the errors.

Comment: tell us the error so we can help and post just the code where the errors happens. We cant read your whole code.

Comment: as I said in the title - the error is Invalid arguments ' .

Comment: Please consider posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I edited the comment -
the error happen when i try to use one of my get function on parameter inside member functions. the error is Invalid arguments ' .

Comment: @OmerEliyahu copy and paste the actual error message into the question.

Comment: Your example is not *Complete* because `SquareType` and `EMPTY` aren't defined.

Comment: Just comment "for the rest of code": do not use `if(thisRatio==paramRatio)` when `thisRatio` and/or `paramRatio` are `float` or `double`, use `<=` or `<` and consider applying some delta to compare difference between `thisRatio` and `paramRatio`

Comment: I have edited the whole post , the problem is to use getTotalArea() in member functions.

Comment: @OmerEliyahu `int getTotalArea();` is missing a `const`: `int getTotalArea() const;`

Answer (score 2):

From the answer of PcAF seems you've heavily changed your initial post without modifying your question. **Very bad**!

However, the problem you're facing now with `getTotalArea` is that it isn't declared `const`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/751690/781933 for explanation.

Comment: Still i can't understand why my code cannot go through compilation. the compiler know if I dont change anything and force me to declare it as const ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you misunderstood operator  overloading (as members)

When overloading some operator as member, then first operand of that operator is object **on which member operator overload is called** and second operand is parameter to that function (in case of binary operators).

operator `+` can be used as binary(2 operands) or unary operator(1 operand).

Here it seems like you want to overload binary version as member:

```
Apartment operator+(const Apartment& apartment1,const Apartment& apartment2);
```

but since first operand is object on which that member "function" is called it must take only 1 parameter (which is second operand).

```
Apartment operator+(const Apartment& apartment2);
```

Here is the second mistake:

```
Apartment& operator=(SquareType** squares, int length, int width, int price);
```

operator `=` is binary operator (2 operands), therefore if you want to overload it as member function it has to take exactly one parameter (which is second operand of `=`), not 4 parameters.

Comment: i know that , I removed it from the class . It's non member operand anymore.

Comment: I've updated my answer, also I recommend you to learn something about *operator overloading*, because it seems that you don't quite understand it.

Comment: Thank you for your help .
do you have any idea about the error that I got ?