# Gtest, equals object

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, googletest

I want equals 2 objects, exactly cards (unit test with gtest).
This is my code:

```
   #include "stdafx.h"
#include <gtest\gtest.h>
#include <vector>

class Card {
public:
    Card(int value, int color) :value(value), color(color) {};
    int returnColor() const { return color; };
    int returnValue() const { return value; };
    bool operator==(const Card &card) {
        return returnValue() == card.returnValue();
    };
private:
    int value;
    int color;
};

class CardTest : public ::testing::Test {
protected:
    std::vector<Card> cards;
    CardTest() { cards.push_back(Card(10, 2));
    cards.push_back(Card(10, 3));
    };
};
TEST_F(CardTest, firstTest)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(cards.at(0), cards.at(1));
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

I have error:

> State Error   C2678   binary '==': no operator found which takes a
>   left-hand operand of type 'const Card' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion)

I try overload operator '==', but this not working :/
Maybe, I must go other way?
This is my first unit test :D.

Comment: That error point line 1448 in gtest.h

Comment: `bool operator==(const Card &card) const { ...` ? In other words, the function should not only promise not to mutate the reference it is given, it should also promise not to mutate `this`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equality operator needs to be `const`:

```
bool operator==(const Card &card) const {
                                  ^^^^^
```

For a discussion of const methods, see 
 [Meaning of "const" last in a C++ method declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751681/meaning-of-const-last-in-a-c-method-declaration)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
bool operator ==(const Card& card) {
    return returnValue() == card.returnValue();
}
```

I think you just have the & in the wrong place.

Comment: yep, I try and this is the same like my solution