# Not maintaining iterator dereferenceability?

Tags: c++, iterator, doubly-linked-list, dereference

Here is a first attempt at iterator of a doubly linked list:

`dlist.h`

```
#ifndef dlist_h
#define dlist_h

/* Node */
template <class Elem>
struct Link
{
    Link();
    Link (Link<Elem>* s, Link<Elem>* p, const Elem& v);
    Link (const Link<Elem>& src);

    Link<Elem>& operator= (const Link<Elem>& src);

    bool operator== (const Link<Elem>& src);
    bool operator!= (const Link<Elem>& src);

    void swap(Link<Elem>& src);

    Link* succ;
    Link* prev;
    Elem val;
};


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
/* Doubly Linked List */
template <class Elem>
class List
{ 
public:
    class iterator;

    List();

    iterator begin() { return iterator(first, first, last); }
    iterator end() { return iterator(last, first, last); }

    void push_front(const Elem& v);
    Elem& front();

    size_t size(); 
    void print();

private:
    Link<Elem> *first;
    Link<Elem> *last;
};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
/* a range-checked bidirectional iterator */
template <class Elem>
class List<Elem>::iterator
{
public:
    iterator();                                         // default constructor
    iterator(Link<Elem>* c, Link<Elem>* b, Link<Elem>* e);                  
    iterator(const iterator& src);                      // copy constructor
    iterator operator= (const iterator& src);           // copy assignment 

    iterator& operator++();                             // incrementations
    iterator operator++(int);                           // postfix
    iterator& operator--();                             // decrementations
    iterator operator--(int);                           // postfix

    Elem& operator*();                                  // dereferenceable lvalue
    const Elem& operator*() const;                      // dereferenceable rvalue

    bool operator== (const iterator& b) const;          // equality comparisons
    bool operator!= (const iterator& b) const;

    void swap(iterator& src);

private:
    Link<Elem>* curr;
    Link<Elem>* begin;
    Link<Elem>* end;
};

#include "dlist.cpp"

#endif
```

`dlist.cpp`

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <class Elem>
Link<Elem>::Link()
    : succ(nullptr), prev(nullptr), val(Elem())
{

}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <class Elem>
Link<Elem>::Link (Link<Elem>* s, Link<Elem>* p, const Elem& v)
    : succ(s), prev(p), val(v)
{

}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <class Elem>
Link<Elem>::Link (const Link<Elem>& src)
   : succ(src.succ), prev(src.prev), val(src.val)
{

}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class Elem>
Link<Elem>& Link<Elem>::operator= (const Link<Elem>& src)
{
    Link<Elem> temp(src);
    swap(*this, temp);
    return *this;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class Elem>
bool Link<Elem>::operator== (const Link<Elem>& src)
{
    return succ = src.succ && prev = src.prev;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <class Elem>
bool Link<Elem>::operator!= (const Link<Elem>& src)
{
    return !(*this == src);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template <class Elem>
void Link<Elem>::swap(Link<Elem>& src)
{
    std::swap(prev, src.prev);
    std::swap(succ, src.succ);
    std::swap(val, src.val);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<class Elem>
void swap(Link<Elem>& lhs, Link<Elem>& rhs)
{
    lhs.swap(rhs);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<class Elem> 
List<Elem>::List()
    : first(new Link<Elem>()), last(first)
{

}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<class Elem>
void List<Elem>::push_front(const Elem& v)
{  
    first = new Link<Elem>(first, nullptr, v); 
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<class Elem>
Elem& List<Elem>::front()
{
    return first->val; 
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<class Elem>
size_t List<Elem>::size() 
{
    size_t count = 0;
    for (iterator p = begin(); p != end(); ++p)
    {
        ++count;     
    }
    return count;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<class Elem>
void List<Elem>::print()
{
    for (iterator p = begin(); p != end(); ++p)
    {
         std::cout << *p <<' ';  
    }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<class Elem>
List<Elem>::iterator::iterator()
    : curr(nullptr), begin(nullptr), end(nullptr)
{

}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<class Elem>
List<Elem>::iterator::iterator(Link<Elem>* p, Link<Elem>* b, Link<Elem>* e)
    : curr(p), begin(b), end(e)
{

}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<class Elem>
List<Elem>::iterator::iterator(const iterator& src)
    : curr(src.curr), begin(src.begin), end(src.end)
{

}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<class Elem>
typename List<Elem>::iterator List<Elem>::iterator::operator= (const iterator& src)
{
    iterator temp(src);
    this->swap(temp);
    return *this;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<class Elem>
typename List<Elem>::iterator& List<Elem>::iterator::operator++()
{
    if (curr == end)
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("List<Elem>::iterator::operator++(): out of range!\n");
    }

    curr = curr->succ;

    return *this; 
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<class Elem>
typename List<Elem>::iterator List<Elem>::iterator::operator++(int)
{
    if (curr == end)
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("List<Elem>::iterator::operator++(): out of range!\n");
    }

    Link<Elem>* old = curr;
    curr = curr->succ;
    return old; 
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<class Elem>
typename List<Elem>::iterator& List<Elem>::iterator::operator--()
{ 
    if (curr == begin)
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("List<Elem>::iterator::operator--(): out of range!\n");
    }

    curr = curr->prev;

    return *this; 
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<class Elem>
typename List<Elem>::iterator List<Elem>::iterator::operator--(int)
{ 
    if (curr == begin)
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("List<Elem>::iterator::operator--(): out of range!\n");
     }

     iterator old(*this);
     curr = curr->prev; 
     return old; 
 }

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<class Elem>
Elem& List<Elem>::iterator::operator*() 
{ 
    return curr->val; 
}   

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<class Elem>
const Elem& List<Elem>::iterator::operator*() const
{  
    return curr->val;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<class Elem> 
bool List<Elem>::iterator::operator== (const iterator& b) const
{ 
    return curr == b.curr; 
} 

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<class Elem>
bool List<Elem>::iterator::operator!= (const iterator& b) const
{ 
    return curr != b.curr; 
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<class Elem>
void List<Elem>::iterator::swap(iterator& src)
{
    std::swap(curr, src.curr); 
    std::swap(begin, src.begin);
    std::swap(end, src.end);
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<class Elem>
void swap(typename List<Elem>::iterator& lhs, typename List<Elem>::iterator& rhs)
{
    lhs.swap(rhs);
}
```

`main.cpp`

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include "dlist.h"
 /* simple test for iterator */ 

int main() 
{
    List<int> l;
    l.push_front(1);
    l.push_front(2);
    l.push_front(3);
    l.push_front(4);
    l.push_front(5);

    // default constructor, copy assignment
    List<int>::iterator p = l.begin();

    // lvalue dereferencing 
    *p = 100;

    // incrementation, rvalue dereferencing
    List<int>::iterator i;
    for (i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << *i <<' ';
    }

    if (i == l.end() && i != l.begin())
    {
        std::cout <<"\ncomparison correct!\n";
    }

    // postfix and prefix decrementation; maintain dereferenceability

    List<int>::iterator ii = l.end();
    --ii;
    for (; ii != l.begin(); ii--)
    {
        std::cout << *ii <<' ';
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

When it reaches the last `for` loop the decrement `operator--` somehow invalidates the `ii` iterator and I can't figure it out despite a thorough<sup>IMO</sup> debugging.

Here is a [runnable sample](http://ideone.com/hX4Bfe).

---

Comment: You never set any link's prev pointer, they are always null. `operator--` will always assign `curr = curr->prev;` which is essentially `curr = nullptr;`.

Comment: Erratum : you assign `prev` once, accidentally in `Link<Elem>::operator==`.

Comment: Why does your `iterator` need 3 pointers? Only `curr` should be enough.

Comment: @tntxtnt for range checking.

Comment: I see. However, std::list::iterator only needs 1 pointer because std::list is circular. Since you have a default node I think you can use it as your end() iterator. You don't need `begin` or `end` to check the validity of `curr`. If `curr` is not null then it is valid. So you need only 1 pointer in iterator.

Comment: I strongly suggest deriving your iterator class from [boost::iterator_facade](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html). It avoids much of the boilerplate like having to write both pre- and postfix operators and makes your iterator standard compliant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `push_front` method, you forgot to link `first->succ->prev` back to new node, hence your doubly linked list is basically a singly linked list

The first `i--` succeed because `last` points to a default node, but `curr->prev` is a nullptr since you forgot to link back, so the next `i--` will deref the nullptr `curr` cause the error.

Fix your push_front method:

```
template<class Elem>
void List<Elem>::push_front(const Elem& v)
{
    first = new Link<Elem>(first, nullptr, v);
    first->succ->prev = first; //link back
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor for `Link` does not properly update the elements given as arguments. Inserting an element between two elements breaks the previous link.

This is a more appropriate constructor :

```
template <class Elem>
Link<Elem>::Link(Link<Elem>* s, const Elem& v)
    : succ(s), prev(s->prev), val(v)
{
    // Update next and previous nodes to make them aware of this
    s->prev = this;
    if(prev) prev->succ = this;
}
```

If you update `List::push_front` to use this constructor instead, you will find that your code compiles and runs.

You should consider making methods `const` when appropriate to avoid mistakes (or to spot existing onw them in the case of `bool operator== (const Link<Elem>& src) const`). [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751681/meaning-of-const-last-in-a-c-method-declaration).