# 'return' : cannot convert from 'const class myClass' to 'class myClass &'

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have the function prototype in .h file as:

```
myClass & operator+ (const myClass & myClassInst) const;
```

and the implementation in .cpp file:

```
myClass& myClass::operator+ (const myClass &myClassInst) const
{
    return *this;
}
```

However, when I compile, I get the following message:

```
error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'const class myClass' to 'class 
myClass &'
```

I am a little bit confused by *this here, and I simply couldn't make things correct. Does anybody know how to fix the error here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/920069

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of 'const' last in a function declaration of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751681/meaning-of-const-last-in-a-function-declaration-of-a-class)

Comment: BTW. This operator should not return a reference.

Comment: And it should be a free function, not a member.

Comment: Handy reading: [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: @NeilButterworth there is nothing wrong with defining `operator+` as a member of the class, as long as it follows the rules for input and output. Making it a free function is just a rule of thumb, not set in stone.

Comment: @Remy If you say so - I have never seen operator +, or any other binary operators (except for assignment) defined as anything but free functions, or done so myself. But YMMV.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're returning a **reference** to an object from a member function that you explicitly declared as **const**.

A const member function guarantees that your object and its attributes won't be modified (unless they're declared as [mutable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/mutable)).

By returning a reference to this (*this) the caller of the function can freely change the object and that would break the const member function warranty.

So either make your member function non-const, or don't return a reference.

Comment: Or return a const reference? (Not sure how advisable that is, but it makes the syntax work.)