# Why do I get a compilation error for this program in g++ 4.8.5?

Tags: c++11, g++4.8

I'm trying to solve a problem from an [online judge](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/runs/code/11872651) and the judge uses g++ 4.8.5.

The following program compiles correctly on my machine (g++ 8.2.0) with `-std=c++11 -pedantic-errors`:

```
#include <algorithm>

struct Task {
    int deadline;
    const bool operator<(const Task &o) {
        return deadline < o.deadline;
    }
};
Task tasks[] = {8, 4, 3, 5, 1, 2, 0, 7};

int main()
{
    std::sort(tasks, tasks + 8);
}
```

However, the judge gives me the following errors:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/algorithm:62:0,
                 from Main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of '_RandomAccessIterator std::__unguarded_partition(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, const _Tp&) [with _RandomAccessIterator = Task*; _Tp = Task]':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:2283:70: required from '_RandomAccessIterator std::__unguarded_partition_pivot(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator) [with _RandomAccessIterator = Task*]' /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:2315:54:
required from 'void std::__introsort_loop(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Size) [with _RandomAccessIterator = Task*; _Size = int]' /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:5461:36:
required from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter) [with _RAIter = Task*]' Main.cpp:15:23:
required from here /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:2245:19:
error: passing 'const Task' as 'this' argument of 'const bool Task::operator<(const Task&)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
    while (__pivot < *__last)
       ^
```

The judge compiles with `-std=c++11 -O2 -lm`.

Does g++ 4.8 not fully support C++11? How do I compile this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, GCC 4.8 does support most of C++11, which can be seen [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/cxx0x_status.html). However, this seems to have been an error in GCC 4.8. The exact requirements of `std::sort` are located in Section 25.4 of this [ISO specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf) from 2013.

There it notes that the only requirement on `operator<` is that it implements a "[strict weak ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979759/operator-and-strict-weak-ordering)". It then goes on to define a "strict weak ordering" by its mathematical properties. None of this seems to imply that `operator<` must be const as GCC 4.8 tried to force. The `operator<` could perhaps change an internal variable, and still follow the specification, as long as the booleans returned make a "strict weak ordering". This could be used to count the number of comparisons made on each variable by the `std::sort` function, allowing easier benchmarking of `std::sort` without going into undefined behavior (As just one example of many different possibilities).

Using const must have been an over-assumption on the original implementation of C++11 in GCC 4.8, and was corrected in later versions.

Unfortunately, if the online judge is using that version of GCC, you can't do anything about it. The other answers here specify how to fix it (Namely, making your member function const).

Digging into GCC's history, we can see that it was changed [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blobdiff;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h;h=36f03a40539843b6540e8518c8acae70e1e832ff;hp=b06211e0100948844f2704c1ed9b21ae69a9fb6e;hb=d6afb2354ee741cf9eb0575beaf4849d5c28f875;hpb=1dd7fae50405fb48e4f2899422e8932840b9c9a6), on 2013-09-27. It seemed like a larger refactor that might not've paid attention to intricacies, but the contributer did remove `const` in several areas so it appeared to be intentional. The commit msg isn't too enlightening either. If you want you can email him, see if he remembers xD

Comment: In fact, it doesn't seem to imply that it returns a boolean either. It's only checking the value of `a < b != false`, according to its definition "contextually converted to bool".

Answer (score 3):

```
const bool operator<(const Task &o) {
```

should be

```
bool operator<(const Task &o) const {
```

It doesn't make sense for the return value to be `const`, and as a comparison operator it doesn't need to modify `*this`.

The error message says `passing 'const Task' as 'this' argument of 'const bool Task::operator<(const Task&)' discards qualifiers`, so somewhere in the bowels of `std::sort` it's trying to call `operator<` on a `const Task` object. Your original `tasks` array is not `const`, so this is presumably because `std::sort` is calling a helper function that takes a `const Task &` (because the helper function doesn't need to modify anything).

The call fails because your `operator<` wasn't declared as `const` (i.e. callable on a `const` object).

I'm not sure what's different about g++ 8.2, but apparently the implementation of `std::sort` has changed so it doesn't refer to `const T` objects internally anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Notice this line in the error message

```
error: passing 'const Task' as 'this' argument of 'const bool Task::operator<(const Task&)' discards qualifiers
```

`std::sort` expects the `operator<` for your object to not modify the object itself. You need to indicate the fact that your comparison operator does not mutate the object's state by explicitly marking it as `const`.

The correct version would look something like

```
struct Task {
    int deadline;
    const bool operator<(const Task &o) const {
        return deadline < o.deadline;
    }
};
```

Refer to this link for more info: [Meaning of 'const' last in a function declaration of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751681/meaning-of-const-last-in-a-function-declaration-of-a-class)

Comment: His question was more about why g++ 4.8 is different from g++ 8, i dont think either answers answer the original question. If it is wrong, shouldn't g++ 8 fail?