# Function's const meaning for the return data type

Tags: c++, function, constants, class-design

What is the real **const** meaning for the 2nd declaration foo:B() ?

```
int foo::A() const {
    return m_var; 
}


int const foo::B() {
    return m_var; 
}
```

For the 1st declaration I know for sure that it "protects" the member variable ie m_var.

But what the whole meaning of the 2nd declaration, which it just returns a constant int to the caller probably non-constant variable  ? I mean does this make sense for any reason ?

Comment: Returning a `const` value makes no sense at all.

Comment: Not only that, the type of the expression `f.B()` for a made up `foo f;` is `int`. So I would say it makes negative sense for fundamentals value types. Pre C++11 there was marginal sense to do it for some user defined types. Now there is none.

Comment: with or without the `const`, `f.B() = 5;` is an error, so its meaningless

Comment: that is the wrong dupe. OP has two examples. First is a const method, the question is about the second. Voting to reopen

Comment: @user463035818 I seriously disagree. The two dupes perfectly explained what the `const` keyword does for both of the code examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of 'const' last in a function declaration of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751681/meaning-of-const-last-in-a-function-declaration-of-a-class)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ sorry, I wasnt aware that I can reopen without needing more votes, now I dont have the links anymore. I thought the dupes are about const member functions only

Comment: @user463035818 Here's the 2nd case explained: https://stackoverflow.com/a/751696/1413395

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this question is about returning a `int const´ not about a `const`last in a function declaration (first snippet here)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ still disagree, because this question here is specifically about returning a `const int` wich is meaningless, this is not adressed in the proposed dupe.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ actually I dont care too much about this case, just wanted to explain my point. It was just my fault to not consider that I am not voting but opening the question by the click. Forget that sometimes and wish I could vote again.

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1:** The `const` after the function signature says that the function will not change the object.  So you can use it on `const` objects (or with pointer to `const` or a `const` reference).

**Case 2:** The `const` before the function name is indeed about the return type.  You are completely right: in practice it doesn't change anything for the object, since the return is in this snippet done by value, and this value in a temp that cannot be changed (e.g. a `++` or a `--` would not be valid anyway because there's no lvalue).

**Case 3:** The const in the return type would make more sense with the return of a pointer to const or a const reference. In this case it would prevent the object state to be changed from outside.

Here a summary:

```
class foo {
public:
    int A() const {   // const function
        return m_var; 
    }
    int const B() {   // non const function, but const return type
        return m_var; 
    }
    int const& C() const {   // non const function, but const reference return type
        return m_var; 
    }
private:
    int m_var; 
};

int main() {
    const foo x{}; 
    x.A();                // ok 
    //x.B();              // not ok -> function B() doesn't guarantee to leave x unchanged. 
    x.C();                // ok 
    const int& y = x.C(); // ok  (y will not alter m_var. 
    //int& z = x.C();       // not ok since z is not const 
    return 0;
}
```

[online demo](https://ideone.com/KD12t4)

**Case 4:** (thanks to [HolyBlackCat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2752075/holyblackcat) for pointing it out).  What make no difference for scalars in case 2 could perfectly make sense for classes.   Suppose `m_var` would be of class `bar` :

```
class bar {
public: 
    void change_it() {}  
    void read_it() const {} 
};
```

Then the const return value would make a difference:

```
foo u{}; 
u.B();                // ok 
u.B().read_it();      // ok
u.B().change_it();    // not ok because of constness of B().
```

[online demo](https://ideone.com/4xGDZA)

Comment: If I remember correctly, `const` indeed has no effect when returning arithmetic types. But that's different for classes (e.g. const class instances can't be meaningfully moved from). Though I don't remember the details.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks for pointing it out !  Indeed, it would make sense for a class.  I've edited my answer and gave you credit for this additional case :-)

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning that const class return values prevents `move`ing from them, so their usage is discouraged.