# set one class' object into another class' method

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, googletest, getter-setter

I have to write my method according to this GT testCase:

```
TEST(playerTest, setGameTest) {

    Player p;
    Game g;
    p.setGame(&g);
    EXPECT_EQ(&g, p.getGame());
}
```

Now Player.h has these:

```
Game* game;

void setGame(Game* g);
Game getGame();
```

Player.cpp

```
void Player::setGame(Game* g) {
    this->game =  g;
}


int Player::getGame() {
    return this->game;
}
```

but these don't work with the test due to incompatible pointer types. I would appreciate if I could also get some explanation along with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setter and getter do not have the right signatures

```
void Player::setGame(Game* g)
{
    game = g;
}

Game* Player::getGame() const
{
    return game;
}
```

Comment: The getter doesn't work. Even if change the definition ```Game getGame();```to ```Game* getGame();```

Comment: Note that I added `const` to the end of the method. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751681/meaning-of-const-last-in-a-function-declaration-of-a-class/751694 So the new signature is `Game* getGame() const;`