# no instance of overloaded function std::unordermap.insert

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I declared a stream class, but when defining its member function, it always reports an error when I want to insert something into the private member unordered_map, I want to ask How to solve this?
stream.h

```
#include <unordered_map>

class stream
{
private:
    std::unordered_map<size_t, std::string> word_count;
public:
    void reassemblestream() const;
};
```

stream.cpp

```
#include"stream.h"
using namespace std;
void stream::reassemblestream() const
{
    static  size_t a = 1;
    string fe = "dfi";
    word_count.insert({ 1,"dfs" });
    word_count.insert(make_pair(a, fe));
}
```

error happen in stream.cpp of `word_count.insert` funcion.
This is the error information:

> E1087 There is no overloaded function "std::unordered_map<_Kty, _Ty,
> _Hasher, _Keyeq, _Alloc>::insert [where _Kty=size_t, _Ty=std::string, _Hasher=std:: hash<size_t>, _Keyeq=std::equal_to<size_t>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const size_t, std::string>>]" instance (object contains type qualifiers that prevent matching)

I use visual studio 2019.

Comment: You marked the member function `const`, but then you try to modify the object.

Comment: You can make `word_count` `mutable`, but that defeats the purpose

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks, i'm so stupid, you are right.

Comment: You're not stupid, it's a vague and misleading error message. (It looks like an IntelliSense message, and those are often not very good. You might get a better message if you compile the code.)

Comment: @molbdnilo yeah, i will, thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If build the program with `clang++`, we get more clear error messages:

```
source>:17:16: error: no matching member function for call to 'insert'
    word_count.insert({ 1,"dfs" });
    ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.1.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11.1.0/../../../../include/c++/11.1.0/bits/unordered_map.h:557:7: note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const std::unordered_map<size_t, std::string>' (aka 'const unordered_map<unsigned long, basic_string<char>>'), but method is not marked const
      insert(value_type&& __x)
```

Just remove the `const` qualifiers, since you are modifying the data member by calling the `insert` function, the function `reassemblestream` can't be marked as const(related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751681/meaning-of-const-last-in-a-function-declaration-of-a-class) for const member function):

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

class stream
{
private:
    std::unordered_map<size_t, std::string> word_count;
public:
    void reassemblestream();
};


void stream::reassemblestream() 
{
    static  size_t a = 1;
    std::string fe = "dfi";
    word_count.insert({ 1,"dfs" });
    word_count.insert(make_pair(a, fe));
}
```