# C++ unordered_map insert

Tags: c++

In the following, I am trying to create a graph in C++ I use `unordered_map` to implement the adjacency list:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

class Graph
{
private:
    typedef pair<string, double> neighbor; // [neighbor vertex, weight of the edge to that neighbor]
    unordered_map<string, vector<neighbor>> adjacencyList;

public:
    void addEdge(const vector<string> &equation, int value)
    {
        // e.g. addEdge(["a", "b"], 2.0) will add 2 from a to b and 1/2 from b to a
        neighbor n = make_pair(equation[1], value);
        adjacencyList.insert({equation[0], n});
    }

    int dfs(const string &start, const string &end, int product)
    {
        if (start == end) // string comparison??
        {
            return product;
        }

        for (const neighbor &n : adjacencyList[start])
        {
            dfs(n.first, end, product * n.second);
        }
    }
};

vector<double> calcEquation(vector<vector<string>> &equations, vector<double> &values, vector<vector<string>> &queries)
{
    // [["a","b"],["b","c"]], values = [2.0,3.0], queries = [["a","c"]]
    //
    // a = 2 * b, b = 3 * c

    // draw a graph where the edge from a to b has weight 2, the edge from b to a has weight 1/2, etc
    // also, a

    int n = equations.size();
    Graph G = Graph();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        G.addEdge(equations[i], values[i]); // ["a","b"], 2.0
    }

    // do dfs
}
```

But when I try to use the `insert` method (as shwon in the `addEdge` method), I get the following error:

```
no instance of overloaded function "std::unordered_map<_Kty, _Ty, _Hasher, _Keyeq, _Alloc>::insert [with _Kty=std::string, _Ty=std::vector<Graph::neighbor, std::allocator<Graph::neighbor>>, _Hasher=std::hash<std::string>, _Keyeq=std::equal_to<std::string>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, std::vector<Graph::neighbor, std::allocator<Graph::neighbor>>>>]" matches the argument list
```

I got the same error when trying `adjacencyList.insert(make_pair(equation[0], n))`.

I also read [no instance of overloaded function std::unordermap.insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68723338/no-instance-of-overloaded-function-stdunordermap-insert) and removed the `const` qualifier before the `equation` parameter, but that didn't fix the problem either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is the type of the `value` argument an `int`, when you really want a `double`?

Comment: Side note, **do not use** `std::pair` unless you are really into template programming. The way you use it is the wrong kind of laziness, std::pair has no semantic meaning (it will not be a new strong type).  Instead of `typedef pair<string, double> neighbor;` just make a struct `struct neighbour { std::string name; double weight; };`. You'll end up with more readable and more typesafe code that way (no more guessing what `.first` and `.second` mean all the time)

Comment: `n` is a neighbour. The map's value type is a vector of neighbours ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without considering why a double is passed when an int is expected by the addEdge function :

`adjacencyList.insert` expects a `std::string`, as well as a `std::vector<neighbor>`.

In the `addEdge` function, you're indeed passing the string : `equation[0]`, however, you're not passing a vector. You're passing a single element, which cannot be implicitly converted as such, resulting in the insert method failing to match.

`n` is neighbor, not a vector of neighbor. A quick fix would be to create a vector of 1 element as such : `adjacencyList.insert({equation[0], {n}});`.

Comment: Pretty sure what OP wants is `adjacencyList[equation[0]].push_back(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

value_type of

```cpp
unordered_map<string, vector<neighbor>> adjacencyList
```

is

```cpp
std::pair<string, vector<neighbor>>
```

this is your errors reason.

---

here some example to expand element for `std::unordered_map`

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
   using el_type = std::vector<int>;
   std::unordered_map<std::string, el_type> map;
   map["1"].push_back(58);
   map["1"].push_back(96);
   map["2"].push_back(10);
   map["2"].push_back(96);

   map.insert({"3", el_type{4,85}});

   for(auto& [key, el]:map){
        std::cout << "key=" << key << "\n";
        for(auto& val:el){
            std::cout << val << "\n";
        }
   }
/*
result might be (key order might different )  
key=2
10
96
key=3
4
85
key=1
58
96
*/
}
```