# Why does >> operator gives error on const file in C++?

Tags: c++, file, constants, operators

I have this piece of code:

```
void NeighborsList::insertVertexes(const ifstream & inputFile)
{
    int tempS, tempT;
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfVertexes; i++)
    {
        inputFile >> tempS;
        inputFile >> tempT;
        addEdge(tempS, tempT);
    }
}
```

where I'm trying to get the input for a file.
Once I remove the const in the function parameter - (ifstream & inputFile) it works.

Comment: Reading from an `ifstream` _changes_ the stream.  `const` variables reject change.

Comment: Remember the const is on the stream object not the actual file. To read the ifstream object must change.

Comment: This question may need some _clarity_.  Do you understand that extracting an `int` from an `ifstream` will modify the ifstream?  Do you understand what `const` does to a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a `const` object or reference, only [`const` operations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/751681/10077) may be performed. [`std::istream::operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) is *not* a `const` operation, therefore it may not be used here.

It makes sense that `std::istream::operator>>` is not a `const` operation, because it alters the observable state of the stream. The read position on the file is changed, for example, as well as status indicators like `fail` and `eof`.