# Are the following const function equivalent?

Tags: c++

My question is simple. I was programing a getter when I noticed that I forgot the last `const` in my expression. But while I was writing it, I doubted: I know that in `const` function you can't change the returned element, so in the second one the is `const std::vector` implicit?

```
const std::vector<int> foo() const{}
std::vector<int> foo() const{}
```

Comment: you can return whatever you like from a const function, you just cant change the object its invoked on

Comment: That's true, I'm going to edit the question @pm100

Comment: I seem to remember returning a `const` value prevents Return Value Optimization, but I'm not sure if that's still true.

Comment: no the const is not implicit, you are returning a writable vector

Comment: the compiler will tell you if you try to do something invalid when you declare a function const

Comment: so if I'm returning a writable vector, what guarentee the const at the finish of the function? @pm100

Comment: Since the returned `vector` is a value, a copy, you can fold it, spindle it, and mutilate it without affecting the instance you got the copy from. The trailing `const` is satisfied.

Comment: the fact that you did not change this inside foo.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751681/meaning-of-const-last-in-a-function-declaration-of-a-class

Comment: It will be returning a copy by the way and that's missing from the body also there shouldn't be semicolons at the ends there.

Answer (score 1):

You can return non-const values. You cannot return a non-const reference. Both of these functions return a *copy*, thus the const for the return type is not required.

If you were to return

```
std::vector<int> &
```

Then you would need the const.

Answer (score 1):

Your concern is that if you are rturning a reference to data from within the object does that have to be const. Yes. This

```
class Test {
    int m_num;
public:
    int& getNum()   const { return m_num; }
};
```

does not compile. You need

```
class Test {
    int m_num;
public:
    const int& getNum()   const { return m_num; }
};
```

your case with a vector

```
class Test {
    int m_num;
    std::vector<int> m_vec;
public:
    const int& getNum()   const { return m_num; }
    std::vector<int> getVec()   const { return m_vec; }
};
```

works fine because you are returning a copy

but this is not ok

```
class Test {
    int m_num;
    std::vector<int> m_vec;
public:
    const int& getNum()   const { return m_num; }
    std::vector<int> & getVec()   const { return m_vec; }
};
```

has to be

```
class Test {
    int m_num;
    std::vector<int> m_vec;
public:
    const int& getNum()   const { return m_num; }
    const std::vector<int> & getVec()   const { return m_vec; }
};
```