# Read-only block in C++

Tags: c++

In C++, it is possible to declare a member function with the `const` keyword so that it cannot modify the object ([except possibly it's mutable fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/751783)).

Question: is there a way to write **only a block** so that it cannot modify the object?

As an example, I imagine it might look like this:

```
class A {
    void f() { // non-const member
        ... // this code might modify *this
        const {
            ... // this code cannot modify *this
        }
        ...
    }
};
```

We can achieve this with a function call like this:

```
class A {
    void _f() const {
        ... // this code cannot modify *this
    }
    void f() { // non-const member
        ... // this code might modify *this
        _f();
        ...
    }
};
```

I am wondering if there is a way around that.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to mark only a block as `const`. But as you demonstrated, you can extract this block into a separate method and make it `const`. Do you have any actual problem that cannot be solved like that ?

Comment: What problem would this solve?

Comment: C++ has no concept of marking an arbitrary block of code as const. Moving such code into a const class method, or into a freestanding function or lambda with a const parameter, or even just using a local const pointer/reference to the object, is the only way.

Comment: I have seen similar quesiton before. THe answer is no. You can invent some fancy stuff but none actually prevents you from still modifying the object. For example you can use `const auto& const_ref = *this;` and then use `const_ref`, but `this` is still in scope

Comment: What's the problem with writing the `const` method that you're trying to avoid by using a `const` block? Developer overhead? Ease of reading/maintenance? Compute cycles?

Comment: AustinBest, I'm also very curious about _why_ you want this.  What's the use-case? Why would you want such a nameless block? Wouldn't it be better to name it (put it in a `const`-qualified function) and call it from the non-`const`-qualified function?

Answer (score 7):

Using an immediately invoked lambda expression you can get very close:

```
class A {
    void f() { // non-const member
        ... // this code might modify *this
        [](const auto& self){
            //error, foo cannot be used since it was not captured
            //foo = 42;
            // error, this does not get implicitly captured when used
            //this->foo;
            // error, self is const
            //self.foo = 42;
            // fine, no modification and uses self to refer to the object
            std::cout << self.foo;
        }(*this);
        ...
    }
    int foo = 0;
};
```

Comment: me fool thought that `this` is implicitly captured by the lambda and wrote it all by hand :D.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Yeah, you have to explicit capture it, even using `this` inside the lambda without capturing doesn't implicitly capture it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
class A {
    void f() { 
         { 
             const auto& self = *this;
             // self is const
         }
    }
};
```

However, `this` is still in scope.

You can also declare a custom functor that takes a `const` reference:

```
struct foo {
    void f() {
        struct foobar {
            void operator()(const foo& x) { 
                // x is const here                
            }
        };
        foobar{}(*this);
    }
};
```

Not sure if this counts as "only a block". It is local to the method. It works. The `foo` `this` is not in scope. That's about all for the advantages. It is definitely not worth the hassle.

Note that the above is trying to resemble an immediately-invoked lambda expression, that you can also see in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78239166/4117728).

Your workaround is the most clear solution I can think of. I would not actually call it a workaround. The way to execute a block of code and be in control of what variables can be modified in this block is to write a function.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you cannot mark a block scope as `const` (or similar) to specify that `*this` should not be modified.