# C++ Constructor Parameters Question

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, constructor, constants

I'm learning C++. I have a simple class named GameContext:

```
class GameContext {
    public:
        GameContext(World world);
        virtual ~GameContext();
};
```

To initialize a `GameContext` object, I need a `World` object.

- Should the GameContext constructur take a **pointer** to a World object (`World*`), the address to a World object (`&World`) or a **reference** to a World object (World)?
- What is the `const` keyword when used near a parameter? For example: `GameContext(const World &world)`

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, teminology: You're right that a `World *` would be a pointer to a World object. A `World &`, however, would be a reference to a World object. A `World` would be a *copy* of the World object, not a reference to it.

The `const` (used primarily with a pointer or reference, as in `World const &world` or `World const *world`) means that you're getting a reference/pointer to a const object -- in other words, you're not allowed to modify the original object to which it refers/points.

For small objects, you usually want to pass a copy. For large objects, you'll typically want to pass a const reference. There are exceptions to this, but that's a reasonable rule of thumb to use until you've learned enough more to know when to break the rules (so to speak).

Just based on the name, I'd guess your World object is probably large enough that you probably want to pass it by const reference, so your ctor should look like:

```
GameContext(World const &world);
```

Answer (score 4):

Ideally, you should accept a `const` reference to `World`:

```
class GameContext {
    public:
        GameContext(const World& world);
        virtual ~GameContext();
};
```

First, so that no copying happens when passing the `world`. Second, `const` is keyword that means that you aren't going to change the passed parameter which is `world` in this case.

Comment: I agree. This is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, then you call it like so: `World world; GameContext context(world);`?

Answer (score 1):

Your terminology is way off.

In C++ terminology the terms *pointer* and *address* are synonyms (as far as we are talking about values). In order to take the pointer (or the address) you have to declare your parameter as `World* world`.

To take the reference, the parameter should be declared as `World& world`.

To take a copied value, the parameter should be declared as `World world`.

Which declaration you should use in each specific case depends on our intent. Assuming that `World` is a non-trivial object, the choice should normally be limited to either reference `World& world` or pointer `World* world`.

If you don't intend to modify the source `World` object in `GameContext`'s constructor, a `const` should be added: `const World& world` or `const World* world`.

Finally, passing by pointer allows you to pass a "reserved" value - a null pointer - but at the same time prevents you from passing a pointer to a non-lvalue. If this does not matter much to you, then you should probably stick with a reference `const World& world`.

Comment: "In C++ terminology the terms pointer and address are synonyms" -> I disagree. Bytes are identified by addresses, whereas objects are identified by pointers. See [basic.compound] in the standard.

Comment: @FredOverflow: In value context the document uses the terms *address* and *pointer* interchangeably. I don't see any restrictions to "bytes" only. See the description of unary `&` for example. The only case when one can insist on a distinction is the object context: pointers as objects are not normally referred to as "addresses", only their values are.

Comment: See [intro.memory] which says "Every
byte has a unique **address**." whereas "The result of the unary & operator is a **pointer** to its operand." [expr.unary.op] But you are right in the sense that most *people* tend to use these terms interchangeably :)

Comment: @FredOverflow: No, quite the opposite, most people tend to insist on the distiction, which doesn't really exist in reality. [intro.memory] is not trying to define the term "address". 5.3.1 proceeds to say "the address of an object of type “cv T” is “pointer to cv T,”. 13.4 is titled "Address of overloaded function", which would be totally meaningless under your interpretation of the term "address". Once again, in value context the terms "pointer" and "address" are exact synonyms in the standard language.

Answer (score 1):

`World` is not a reference to a `World` object - the compiler is making a copy of the structure and passing it through the stack. This is bad.

A pointer (`World*`) and a reference (`World&`) are very similar, they differ only in syntax (`->` vs `.`) and scope (you can't assign a reference, so the member `m_pWorld` can't point to another World during the lifetime of your GameContext if you use a reference - but you can do that if you use a pointer). My advice is get a reference if you'll always use the same World (likely), or a pointer otherwise.

The `const` there tells the compiler you won't modify the object. When you get a reference to an object, you're working on **the** object, not a copy of it - so anything you modify in the method actually modifies the "outside" object. In your case, since you'll probably modify or otherwise operate on your `World` within `GameContext`, you probably want a non-const reference.

So you should do something like this

```
class GameContext 
{
public:
    GameContext (World& pWorld) : m_pWorld(pWorld)
    {
    }

    virtual ~GameContext () { ... }

    void foo (int nParam)
    {
        m_pWorld.bar(nParam);
    }

private:
    World& m_pWorld;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference are safer than pointers and involve no copy. As for the const keyword read the answer to this question I made some time ago: [How many and which are the uses of "const" in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455518/how-many-and-which-are-the-uses-of-const-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

The `const` means that the method `GameContext` wont be able to modify the contents of the parameter `world`

Answer (score 0):

> Should the GameContext constructur
>   take a pointer to a World object
>   (World*), the address to a World
>   object (&World) or a reference to a
>   World object (World)?

First of all, the "address to a `World` object" is the same thing as a pointer to a `World` object. A pointer is a type of variable that stores an object's address. If you pass an address, then the parameter that corresponds to the address you passed will be a pointer.

Whether you want to take a pointer or not depends on the semantics of the `World` class. If you take a value (and not a pointer), then you will receive a *copy* of the World object passed in. If something other than the `GameContext` object needs to perform operations on that *same* world object, then you will want to pass in and store a pointer. If this is not necessary, or if the `World` class operates internally such that all copies of a `World` object use a common set of data, then you can pass by value.

> What is the const keyword when used
>   near a parameter? For example:
>   GameContext(const World &world)

`const` means "cannot be modified", just like it means anywhere else. A common idom in C++, as you have given in your example, is to take a constant reference instead of taking a value. When the parameter is an object (as opposed to a fundamental type like `int` or `bool`), this is more efficient than taking a value, since a copy is not made in this case. However the `const` prevents the function from modifying the referenced parameter, so to the caller, it does not matter than it is a reference.