# what does const mean in c++ in different places

Tags: c++, function-qualifier

What is the difference between

```
    const string& getName() const {return name;}
```

and

```
    string& getName() const {return name;}
```

What does const mean at the beginning and at the end?

Comment: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/const_correctness.html this is a good tutorial on how to use const

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meaning of "const" last in a C++ method declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751681/meaning-of-const-last-in-a-c-method-declaration)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many and which are the uses of "const" in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455518/how-many-and-which-are-the-uses-of-const-in-c)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `const` at the end of the function signature means the method is a *const member function*, so both your methods are const member functions.

The `const` at the beginning means whatever is being returned is const.

The first example is a const method returning a const reference to internal data, and is therefore const-correct.

The second is a const method returning non-const reference to internal data. This is not const-correct because it means you would be able to modify the data of a const object.

A call to a const a method cannot change any of the instance's data (with the exception of mutable data members) and can only call other const methods.

Const methods can be called on const or non-const instances, but non-const methods can only be called on non-const instances.

Answer (score 7):

One returns a `const` reference and is a `const` member function , the other is a `const` member function.

```
const string& getName() const {return name;}
```

the returned `string` can't be modified, and the method is `const` (see below).

```
string& getName() const {return name;}
```

the method can't modify non-`mutable` class members.

Comment: Unrelated: since the function is not in any of scope, it is not a member function but only a function right ? :) (assuming it is not in the header file)

Comment: @phantasmagoria you can't have a non-member const function, so it's definitely in class scope.

Comment: @phantasmagoria That was most likely a line copied directly from the class declaration. Thats why it is one liner.

Comment: Both are const member functions.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore yes that is right then "not modifying the class members" would be irrelevent. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We use `const` in the prefix of the function to ensure whatever is getting returned from the function becomes constant.

And we use `const` as the postfix in the function declaration to ensure that the function does not do any modification in the current instance of class i.e if the member function of the class tries to modify the current object's attribute's value then the compiler will throw an error.

**const function** is mainly used for **const object** to ensure that the function is not trying to modify current object data.

Answer (score 1):

```
const string& getName() const {return name;}
```

return const reference means that you will not be able the instance after returning the reference to it.

```
string& getName() const {return name;}
```

const method means that this method will not change the state of the object except the mutable member variables. Also this method can be called on an const object for example:

```
class MyClass(){
public:
  void doSomethingElse()const;
  void notConstMethod();
};

void doSomething( const MyClass& obj ){
  obj.doSomethingElse();
  obj.notConstMethod(); //Error
}
```

Comment: Guys I can't insert the code tags and have not options at all. What happening?