# c++ two versions of overloading subscript operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, subscript

My question is about the difference between:

```
const T& operator[](const int nIndex) const;
```

and:

```
T& operator[](const int nIndex);
```

Why would I need both of them defined in a class, what's the purpose? Wouldn't the latter suffice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what does const mean in c++ in different places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482455/what-does-const-mean-in-c-in-different-places)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A member function declaration with `const` at the end of it allows that function to be called even on a `const` object. This only makes sense for member functions that don't modify the state of the object.

Let's say the class you have that overloads these operators is called `X`. Presumably it behaves a bit like a container, giving access to the elements it contains through this `operator[]`.

Now let's say the user wants to use a `const X`:

```
const X x = /* fill it */;
use(x[0]);
```

Should the user be allowed to do this? Probably. If they want a container that is immutable, then let them have it. If you didn't provide the `const` version of `operator[]`, they wouldn't be able to do this. They're not trying to modify the container after all, they're just looking at its contents.

Now why make the `const` version of `operator[]` return a `const` reference? Because it has to. It's returning a reference to a member of the class itself. If the container was `const` and returned a non-`const` reference, the caller would be able to modify its internals just by using this operator:

```
const X x = /* fill it */;
x[0].modify();
```

Oh dear, we modify the state of `x` even though it's `const`. This would be bad and in fact, the compiler won't even let you do it.

Comment: I would add that 2 similar overloaded methods (const and non-const) is an often boilerplate in C++

Comment: @sftrabbit: silly follow-up: Do I understand correctly that still I need to define two separate bodies of the const and non-const versions of the operators, and that these bodies will be exactly the same? Basically, smth like return MyDataStructure[nIndex]?

Comment: @SimonRighley Yes, you'll need to define both of them. You *could* define the non-`const` version in terms of the `const` version but then you'd have to do a `const_cast`. You're better off just having the duplicate implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Those are member functions of a class, and the version will be chosen based on whether that class in used as a `const` context.

This version will be called when `[]` is used on a object in a `const` context.  It preserves the `const`-ness of the returned element.

```
const T& operator[](const int nIndex) const;
```

This version will be called when `[]` is used on a non-`const` object.  It specifies that when your object isn't `const`, you'll get an element that you can modify, allowing code like `myObject[0] = 10;`

```
T& operator[](const int nIndex);
```

Answer (score 3):

The first one

> const T& operator[](const int nIndex) const;

is a constant method(function) ie it  guarantees that it would not change any of the class member variable(unless its mutable).

It also returns a constant object which means you can call only constant function i.e you can call only functions that have const at the end similar to the one above.

> T& operator[](const int nIndex);

This method may change the member variables and returns an object that can call any class methods.

We need them both because the constant object would be using the constant method and non constant would be using the other one.

Answer (score 2):

If the object you're accessing is `const`, you don't want to be able to modify it. The compiler wouldn't let you call the non-`const` version of the function.

```
const vector<int> mints;

mints[3] = 5; // not allowed by compiler
```