# Why using the const keyword before and after method or function name?

Tags: c++

I have the following code in my application. Why do we use the `const` keyword with the return type and after the method name?

```
const T& data() const { return data_; }
```

Comment: is the method overloaded?

Comment: This is a part of [Const-correctness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness).

Comment: possible duplicate of [what does const mean in c++ in different places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482455/what-does-const-mean-in-c-in-different-places)

Comment: Note that this only applies to member functions, and there's a good reason for that

Comment: how about "`const T * const const_iterator::data() const`" for a function that makes you doubletake.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

```
const T& get_data() const { return data_; }
^^^^^
```

means it will return a `const` reference to `T` (here `data_`)

```
Class c;
T& t = c.get_data()             // Not allowed.
const T& tc = c.get_data()      // OK.
```

---

---

```
const T& get_data() const { return data_; }
                    ^^^^^
```

means the method will not modify any member variables of the class (unless the member is `mutable`).

```
void Class::get_data() const {
   this->data_ = ...;  // is not allowed here since get_data() is const (unless 'data_' is mutable)
   this->anything = ... // Not allowed unless the thing is 'mutable'
}
```

Comment: unless they've been defined as `mutable` ;)

Comment: @mwerschy Correct. Edited.

Comment: Looking for more of an explanation in the case of const before the function name...how can a function return a constant ref to T?  Does that mean the function returns the same value every time?  (eg: the address of a static variable)

Comment: Sorry for such late comment but a function member declared with `const` could modify all members of the class (even non-`mutable` ones) via `const_cast`ing of a `this` pointer.

Answer (score 34):

The `const` (and `volatile`) qualifier **binds to the left**. This means that any time you see `const`, it is being applied to the token to the left of it. There is one exception, however; if there's nothing to the left of the `const`, it binds to the right, instead. It's important to remember these rules.

In your example, the first `const` has nothing to the left of it, so it's binding to the right, which is `T`. This means that the return type is a reference to a `const T`.

The second const does have something to the left of it; the function `data()`. This means that the `const` will bind to the function, making it a `const` function.

In the end, we have a *const function returning a reference to a const T*.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, these two code snippets are equivalent. `const T& foo () const` and `T& const foo() const`

Answer (score 10):

The first `const` means the function is returning a `const T` reference.

The second one says that the method is not changing the state of the object. I.e. the method does not change any member variables.

Answer (score 6):

```
const T& data() const { return data_; }
```

const after member function indicates that data is a constant member function and in this member function no data members are modified.

const return type indicates returning a constant ref to T