# What is the difference between int const function(parameters), int function(const parameters), and int function(parameters) const?

Tags: c++, constants

I'm working on an assignment for my CS class and it uses const, and I am kind of confused as to when to use each.

What are the differences between these 3 functions?

```
 int const function(parameters)
 int function(const parameters)
 int function(parameters) const
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449889/why-using-the-const-keyword-before-and-after-method-or-function-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you talking about `c++`:

```
const int function(parameters) // instead of your  int const function(parameters)
```

will return a constant to the `int`

```
int function(const parameters)
```

The parameters will be considered as constant inside the method, which means they will not be changed.

```
int function(parameters) const
```

This function will not change any class variable (if the member is not mutable)

Answer (score 4):

```
int const function(parameters)
```

The `const` is redundant. Declaring a simple type such as `int` as a `const` return value is not useful, although it may help to make the code more self-documenting. If the return type is a reference or pointer however then the story changes.

```
int function(const parameters)
```

The `parameters` passed to `function` are `const` and so can not be modified.

```
int function(parameters) const
```

`function` is a *method* which does not modify any of the member variables in the object instance for which it is being invoked.

Comment: Just to expand on the first case, Effective C++ (3rd ed.) recommends this, to prevent accidentally assigning to a temporary. However, since C++!1, this pattern prevents moving from the temporary (not an issue with `int`, but maybe for class types), so is not recommended.

Comment: Minor nitpick: a const member function allows you to modify mutable data members, and it does not allow you to call non-const member functions, even if these do not modify any non-mutable members.

Comment: And if the object itself is const, then you won't be able to call any non-const and non-static function through it.